# <kbd> elements are way too intrusive

Tags: bug, status-completed, fun, design

`<kbd>` is a great way to mark up text to be entered. But when you use it on Stack Exchange sites, it's really difficult to read. For instance, say I typed this sentence by starting with a <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, then used <kbd>o</kbd>, followed by <kbd>r</kbd>, then <kbd>space</kbd>, you can see that it quickly becomes an unreadable mess of boxes and smashed-together type.

Whoever is in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> of the visual design should probably fix it.

Also, I'm so very sorry. Please don't let the silly answers below discourage you from fixing the styling.

Comment: That's why you use them judiciously (goofy, but awesome!, answers below withstanding) and use the necessary white space to make the post look good.  I think it's pretty cool.

Comment: Now all they need is an onclick handler to make them look like you are pressing them. Then an alert box pops up and says "On your keyboard, idiot!".

Comment: ok improved, will deploy later

Comment: Thanks for taking care of the little things like that Jeff.  The polish really does help make this a great site.

Comment: @Macha `jQuery('kbd').click(function(){alert('On your keyboard, idiot!');});`

Comment: @Mache: see [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/74944#74944) :P

Comment: +1, but for [the current rendering](http://i.stack.imgur.com/akMQQ.png) too! Still too ugly, and hardly ever useful in my opinion.

Comment: The kbd graphics are cool in my opinion why get rid of them?

Comment: why doesn't this work on [Math.se]?

Comment: Protected this to prevent at least some of the abusers to abuse the <kbd> tags.

Comment: @Ephraim it appears [to work just fine now](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X6jEB.png), at least in preview

Comment: Got a new MacBook Pro with Touch Bar, just came here for ESC

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```css
kbd {
    -moz-background-clip: border;
    -moz-background-inline-policy: continuous;
    -moz-background-origin: padding;
    background: #EEEEEE none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-color: #CCCCCC #AAAAAA #888888 #BBBBBB;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 2px 2px;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 2px 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

...would make `<kbd>` a bit less broken:

[image: Demonstration of above CSS]

Sadly, it breaks [Pesto's castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974).

Comment: +1: Seems to be the default padding in the SO CSS that is the problem. BUt changing it would probably destroy most of the answers here :-)

Comment: Is this something one can run using Tampermonkey as a script to override the default `<kbd>`...`</kbd>` specification? If so, how do you go about doing that?

Comment: @Werner It would be very easy to do with the "Stylish" addon for Chrome/Firefox. Also definitely doable with Tampermonkey, you'd just need to inject the CSS via Javascript (searching for "tampermonkey add css" should find something).. but in this specific case, why do you need to? The site has been updated to make the kdb element much nicer

Comment: @dbr: Not on [tex.se] where I contribute mostly.

Answer (score 803):

OUR PRINCESS IS IN ANOTHER CASTLE!

---

[image: original keyboard castle]

Comment: You've just beaten the internet.

Comment: I just had a flashback to elementary school and NES-filled nights.. so awesome!

Comment: It probably looks different on every combination of screen size, resolution, font, and operating system. On mine the blank spaces are too small.

Comment: Slow work day, wasn't it?

Comment: Did you use a script for this? Or all by hand...

Comment: A true *artiste* does it all by hand, though there may have been some cut-and-paste.

Comment: Despite being empty of princess, this castle is full of win.

Comment: Oh noes! Now the castle is in another castle!

Comment: I rolled it back now that the `<kbd>` element is back!

Comment: @George, but it looks different?

Comment: @Arjan: Not my fault :P

Comment: But you *did* break the nice result, @George!

Comment: @Arjan: I just rolled it back to the way it was originally!

Comment: No, it did not look like that bad a year ago, did it @George?

Comment: @Arjan: I don't know. I didn't join Meta until about January this year.

Comment: Awesomeness has a new name!!!

Comment: Looking at the side-by-side diffs is even more fun.

Comment: Uh oh. I think the castle is now slightly lopsided. Unexpected geological activity!

Comment: Thanks for freezing my phone 5 times while I scrolled down the answer

Comment: @nhinkle, see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4043/nicer-kbd-style.

Comment: @DragonLord I'm aware.

Comment: The castle has been retrofitted to meet today's earthquake tolerance standards.

Comment: @JeffMercado Hey! I already [did that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/131634#131634). :p

Comment: @ManishEarth: Ah, but your bricks look hand-made with some new features. This one just needed to be [factory remade](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71407) but with the same features.  ;)

Comment: I needed 15+ years to realize that all those castles look indeed like skulls.

Comment: This is a question reporting a now-fixed bug about the behavior of the kbd tag. All of these demonstrations of what the tag can do don't actually answer the question.

Comment: the tension of the right hand side brick on the brink of faling and crashing will keep me up all night.

Answer (score 371):

<kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>      <kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>   <kbd>F5</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>   <kbd>F9</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>   <kbd>PrtSc</kbd><kbd>ScrLk</kbd><kbd>Pse</kbd>


 <kbd>`</kbd>  <kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>5</kbd>  <kbd>6</kbd>  <kbd>7</kbd>  <kbd>8</kbd>  <kbd>9</kbd>  <kbd>0</kbd>  <kbd>-</kbd>  <kbd>=</kbd>   <kbd>←  Bksp</kbd>       <kbd>Ins</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd>

  <kbd>Tab  ↹</kbd>    <kbd>Q</kbd>  <kbd>W</kbd>  <kbd>E</kbd>  <kbd>R</kbd>  <kbd>T</kbd>  <kbd>Y</kbd>  <kbd>U</kbd>  <kbd>I</kbd>  <kbd>O</kbd>  <kbd>P</kbd>  <kbd>[</kbd>  <kbd>]</kbd>  <kbd>\</kbd>     <kbd>Del</kbd>  <kbd>End</kbd>  <kbd>PgDn</kbd>

  <kbd>Caps</kbd>   <kbd>A</kbd>  <kbd>S</kbd>  <kbd>D</kbd>  <kbd>F</kbd>  <kbd>G</kbd>  <kbd>H</kbd>  <kbd>J</kbd>  <kbd>K</kbd>  <kbd>L</kbd>  <kbd>;</kbd>  <kbd>'</kbd>   <kbd>↵  Enter</kbd>    

  <kbd>⇧  Shift</kbd>       <kbd>Z</kbd>  <kbd>X</kbd>  <kbd>C</kbd>  <kbd>V</kbd>  <kbd>B</kbd>  <kbd>N</kbd>  <kbd>M</kbd>  <kbd>,</kbd>  <kbd>.</kbd>  <kbd>/</kbd>    <kbd>⇧  Shift</kbd>                           <kbd>↑</kbd>   

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>    <kbd>⊞</kbd>    <kbd>Alt</kbd>                                                               <kbd>Alt</kbd>    <kbd>⊞</kbd>    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>        <kbd>←</kbd>     <kbd>↓</kbd>     <kbd>→</kbd></kbd>

I'll put the NumPad below, 'cause it wouldn't fit if I placed it beside the keyboard.

<kbd><kbd>Num</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd>  <kbd>*</kbd>  <kbd>-</kbd> 

 <kbd>7</kbd>  <kbd>8</kbd>  <kbd>9</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd>  

 <kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>5</kbd>  <kbd>6</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd> 

 <kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>En</kbd>

      <kbd>0</kbd>       <kbd>.</kbd>  <kbd>ter</kbd></kbd>

This is the most fun I've had all day.

---

[image: original keyboard]

Comment: +1 for the completion of what I tried to do...but also +1 because trying was also the most fun I've had...although...

Comment: Try and change it to the Billy Mays button

Comment: Hey, where's the spacebar?

Comment: Whoneedsaspacebar?

Comment: Now try a UK keyboard with a double height enter key :-)

Comment: are the m, j, l, and i letters on that keyboard (in jeff's link) a little bit red or am I going insane? Maybe I'm a synesthete.

Comment: @Carson Either you're not insane or I am too.

Comment: I can see the red, it might be a result of anti-aliasing, think of the subpixels!

Comment: Updated keyboard to new format :D (with a spacebar, @mmyers :P)

Comment: I made many changes to the keyboard.  I fixed the spacing, so the keyboard looks more rectangular in shape.  I also changed it into a Windows keyboard.  I added function keys.  I replaced arrow keys.  I added 9 keys above the arrow keys.  I added the NumPad.  And lastly, I added the keyboard background and borders.

Answer (score 161):

This is a very old post and the system has changed, it includes the original code for the keyboard and below it the image it generated, currently the original code does not make a good keyboard.

---

Trying out beat Pesto's keyboard. Mine has square buttons and correct spacing between items.

<kbd>°</kbd>  <kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>5</kbd>  <kbd>6</kbd>  <kbd>7</kbd>  <kbd>8</kbd>  <kbd>9</kbd>  <kbd>0</kbd>  <kbd>ö</kbd>  <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd>  
<kbd>Tab</kbd>     <kbd>q</kbd>  <kbd>w</kbd>  <kbd>e</kbd>  <kbd>r</kbd>  <kbd>t</kbd>  <kbd>y</kbd>  <kbd>u</kbd>  <kbd>i</kbd>  <kbd>o</kbd>  <kbd>p</kbd>  <kbd>ð</kbd>  <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>    
<kbd>Caps</kbd>       <kbd>a</kbd>  <kbd>s</kbd>  <kbd>d</kbd>  <kbd>f</kbd>  <kbd>g</kbd>  <kbd>h</kbd>  <kbd>j</kbd>  <kbd>k</kbd>  <kbd>l</kbd>  <kbd>æ</kbd>  <kbd>´</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd>            
<kbd>Shift</kbd>   <kbd><</kbd>  <kbd>z</kbd>  <kbd>x</kbd>  <kbd>c</kbd>  <kbd>v</kbd>  <kbd>b</kbd>  <kbd>n</kbd>  <kbd>m</kbd>  <kbd>,</kbd>  <kbd>.</kbd>  <kbd>þ</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>                 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>        <kbd>❖</kbd>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>                    <kbd>Space</kbd>                   <kbd>Alt</kbd>    <kbd>❖</kbd>   <kbd>Menu</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

---

Original (image form)

[image]

Comment: The right Ctrl key is sticking out to the right for me (on IE7). Is it meant to be flush with the others?

Comment: Here as well (FF3)

Comment: Cant test IE7 :S He is a little bit to the right here but only 1 pixel or so (FF 3.5)

Comment: The right edge of the Shift key is about even with the 'r' in "Ctrl".

Comment: I think it's more that the 4th line is sort.

Comment: Ok wow, well im on linux so the font difference is a possible culprit.

Comment: There's quite a difference on Chrome. The third line is about 1 pixel longer (but that's only noticeable 'cos I'm looking). Oh, don't think I'm not impressed BTW.

Comment: Ok i see the issue in IE now. Ill propose a patch for it soon and commit it to jeff so my keyboard always looks good :D

Comment: @Jeff is this after the change on a Windows machine? Since on Linux this keyboard has about a 10 pixel space between each line. Or is that the intended change?

Comment: Opera v9.64: the right Ctrl key is sticking out to the right.

Comment: @Peter it no longer looks as intended. Check out Jeffs image here in the comments.

Comment: +1 - Thanks for providing those who hadn't seen the old -vs- new, the opportunity to do so. This should be pinned at the top of the answers! :)

Comment: The design of `<kbd>` element has probably changed more than 2 times already, but I like the current keyboard more. It's not bad, just more modern.

Answer (score 160):

I tried to make a keyboard and failed miserably. :(

Although I will present this:

<kbd>Any</kbd>

The mystical Any key.

Answer (score 157):

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>

Or so I'm told.

Comment: I thought we couldn't have nice things because of me. But I guess it was you all along.

Comment: Shouldn't the `T` be a `Shift`+`t`?

Comment: @Chichiray FREE COUNTRY I DO WHAT I WANT

Comment: IN UR POST USIN MY FREEDOMS

Comment: @badp: Because that [*really* needed to be fixed.](http://xkcd.com/386/)

Comment: `Shift` + `t` makes T (as opposed to t^Ht^Httt^H^H^H `Shift` `Shift` `Shift` `Shift` `Shift` `Alt` `y` T).

Answer (score 128):

<kbd>Esc</kbd>     <kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>   <kbd>F5</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>   <kbd>F9</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>  <kbd>PrSn</kbd><kbd>ScLk</kbd><kbd>Brek</kbd>

<kbd>`</kbd>  <kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>5</kbd>  <kbd>6</kbd>  <kbd>7</kbd>  <kbd>8</kbd>  <kbd>9</kbd>  <kbd>0</kbd>  <kbd>-</kbd>  <kbd>=</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd>  <kbd>Ins</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd>  
<kbd>Tab</kbd>   <kbd>q</kbd>  <kbd>w</kbd>  <kbd>e</kbd>  <kbd>r</kbd>  <kbd>t</kbd>  <kbd>y</kbd>  <kbd>u</kbd>   <kbd>i</kbd>   <kbd>o</kbd>  <kbd>p</kbd>   <kbd>[</kbd>    <kbd>]</kbd>    <kbd>\</kbd>          <kbd>Del</kbd>  <kbd>End</kbd> <kbd>PgDn</kbd>
<kbd>Caps</kbd>    <kbd>a</kbd>  <kbd>s</kbd>  <kbd>d</kbd>  <kbd>f</kbd>  <kbd>g</kbd>  <kbd>h</kbd>   <kbd>j</kbd>   <kbd>k</kbd>   <kbd>l</kbd>   <kbd>;</kbd>   <kbd>'</kbd>    <kbd>Enter</kbd>         
<kbd>Shift</kbd>         <kbd>z</kbd>  <kbd>x</kbd>  <kbd>c</kbd>  <kbd>v</kbd>  <kbd>b</kbd>  <kbd>n</kbd>  <kbd>m</kbd>   <kbd>,</kbd>    <kbd>.</kbd>   <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>                             <kbd>▲</kbd>  
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>Win</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>                                                        <kbd>Alt</kbd>   <kbd>Win</kbd> <kbd>Menu</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>    <kbd>◀</kbd>   <kbd>▼</kbd>    <kbd>▶</kbd>

I couldn't find my keyboard layout here, so I thought I'd post it.  You guys are using real small keyboards... (image below for posterity in case the CSS changes in future)

[image: rendered 20-11-2012]

Comment: Best one yet. I am in awe.

Comment: I'm horrified at the amount of time you must have spent on building this! ;)

Comment: Finally, a propper M+104 keyboard layout... though I prefer my [Unicomp 103-key](http://www.pckeyboard.com/page/UltraClassic/UB40P4A), which has original spacing.

Comment: `Brek` sounds pretty funny to me. I was going to suggest `Brk`, but that sounds more like `bark` now.

Answer (score 127):

Felt sorry for the poor broken{*} castle, felt that it MUST be fixed as a tribute to the history of meta.

**Take *THAT*, Jin!!**

<sup>*Today I realised that *non-breaking* spaces can break stuff as well O-0</sup>

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

OUR PRINCESS IS IN ***ANOTHER*** CASTLE!

Comment: Our princess could never be in that castle. It's so... *plain* ... and *white*.

Comment: @ThE blame Jin, not me. ;-)

Comment: I bow to your brick laying skills.

Comment: @Jin: Technically, they're tiles, now that _someone_ changed the design ;-) . Anyway, the design is actually much better--I just felt sorry for the poor castle :P

Comment: [@animuson](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131926/178438) The flag has a unicorn! Try doing _**THAT**_ with inline code blocks!

Comment: `png` files can have clear transparent pixels and pixels in a `jpeg`. [`imgur.com`](http://imgur.com) always converts `.png` to `.jpeg` where every 100% transparent pixel becomes 100% jet black. I have no idea how you got the horse on a bed of grass to show up with a clear transparent background instead of a black one.

Answer (score 109):

<kbd>I totally agree<kbd>I totally agree<kbd>I totally agree<kbd>I totally agree<kbd>I totally agree</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>I totally agree</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

<kbd>this <kbd>is <kbd>another <kbd>pyramid <kbd>lol.</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

<kbd>You know, I totally <kbd>agree.</kbd>

You see, on my posts I'm *never* intrusive, that's why I <kbd>*never*</kbd> use `<kbd></kbd>`</kbd>

### <kbd>**Though I always wanted to make an unpressable button.**</kbd>

And, ladies and gentlemen, the nothing-button!

You <kbd>*see,*</kbd> now that this is <kbd>*fixed,*</kbd>

### I use buttons **`all day long.`**

Comment: Wow it's even worse than backticks... hope it won't become the new formatting trend any time soon!

Comment: Lol, I'm going to start putting all my answers in a Button Nexus like above to draw more attention to them.

Comment: The top two look like a Scratch program when you try to do anything clever!

Answer (score 76):

You don't need keyboards to make castles! Inline code blocks work just as well!

Look, it has a flag! Try doing *that* with keyboards!

P.S. The new keyboard styles are awesomesauce. The unicorns are happy.

Comment: [*cough*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131634/138509)

Comment: @Ullallulloo: Yes, I know, he completed my challenge. Then I threatened to pull out the ASCII art, which I may yet still do.

Comment: @animuson I'm still waiting.

Answer (score 71):

<kbd>Atwood should have never told us about this. This will only end in disaster.</kbd>

Answer (score 71):

I would like to propose that from here on out we replace

<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>

with

<kbd>[Billy Mays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_Mays)</kbd>

> William Darrell "Billy" Mays, Jr.
>   (July 20, 1958 – June 28, 2009) was
>   an American television direct-response
>   advertisement salesperson most notable
>   for promoting OxiClean, Orange Glo,
>   and other cleaning, home-based, and
>   maintenance products. His distinctive
>   beard and loud sales pitches made him
>   a recognized television presence in
>   the United States.

Comment: Seconded. Now only to get PC makers to get on this.

Comment: MAY HE REST IN PEACE!!!

Comment: Was he similar to BRIAN BLESSED?

Comment: [RELATED!](https://johnhaller.com/useful-stuff/billy-mays-caps-lock)

Answer (score 54):

<kbd>▲</kbd><kbd>▲</kbd><kbd>▼</kbd><kbd>▼</kbd><kbd>◄</kbd><kbd>►</kbd><kbd>◄</kbd><kbd>►</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: +1 for an actual legitimate usage of `<kbd>` (plausibly on [gaming.SE](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: Where's `start`?

Answer (score 46):

I couldn't resist:-)

Which computer had this keyboard?

<kbd>⟵</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>5</kbd>  <kbd>6</kbd>  <kbd>7</kbd>  <kbd>8</kbd>  <kbd>9</kbd>  <kbd>0</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd>  <kbd>-</kbd>  <kbd>£</kbd> <kbd>HOME</kbd><kbd>DEL</kbd>      <kbd>f 1</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>Q</kbd>  <kbd>W</kbd>  <kbd>E</kbd>  <kbd>R</kbd>  <kbd>T</kbd>  <kbd>Y</kbd>  <kbd>U</kbd>  <kbd>I</kbd>  <kbd>O</kbd>  <kbd>P</kbd>  <kbd>@</kbd>  <kbd>*</kbd>  <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>RESTORE</kbd>      <kbd>f 3</kbd>

<kbd>RUN</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>  <kbd>S</kbd>  <kbd>D</kbd>  <kbd>F</kbd>  <kbd>G</kbd>  <kbd>H</kbd>  <kbd>J</kbd>  <kbd>K</kbd>  <kbd>L</kbd>  <kbd>:</kbd>  <kbd>;</kbd>  <kbd>=</kbd> <kbd>RETURN</kbd>         <kbd>f 5</kbd>

<kbd>C=</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>  <kbd>X</kbd>  <kbd>C</kbd>  <kbd>V</kbd>  <kbd>B</kbd>  <kbd>N</kbd>  <kbd>M</kbd>  <kbd>,</kbd>  <kbd>.</kbd>  <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>CRSR</kbd><kbd>CRSR</kbd>         <kbd>f 7</kbd>

Comment: I give up. Which is it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Commodore64.jpg

Comment: The function keys give that away, if only from a top view. Its also the C-64C.

Comment: @Tim: there's also a [restore] key; I've never seen that on another system.

Comment: Commodore 64! :D -- too bad we can't include the symbols that go on the sides of the keys.

Comment: Commodore 64, sponsored by [retrocomputing.se]. [meta-tag:shameless-advertising]

Comment: @TimPost Could have been VIC-20, I don't think keyboards were different. Also... _function keys_ give it away? Sure, they were pretty distinctive... but how about the C= key? :D

Answer (score 40):

<kbd>I saw this in an answer once

and have been baffled about how <kbd>it worked</kbd>

ever since then. But I

guess I know now.</kbd> <kbd>I'm terribly sorry about this</kbd>

it looks like a <kbd>label maker</kbd>

Comment: Now it looks like Messages on the iPhone...

Answer (score 38):

Am I late?

<kbd><kbd>esc</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd> <kbd>F5</kbd> <kbd>F6</kbd> <kbd>F7</kbd> <kbd>F8</kbd> <kbd>F9</kbd> <kbd>F10</kbd> <kbd>⏏</kbd>



<kbd><sup>~</sup><sub>`</sub></kbd> <kbd><sup>!</sup><sub>1</sub></kbd><kbd><sup>@</sup><sub>2</sub></kbd> <kbd><sup>#</sup><sub>3</sub></kbd><kbd><sup>$</sup><sub>4</sub></kbd> <kbd><sup>%</sup><sub>5</sub></kbd><kbd><sup>^</sup><sub>6</sub></kbd> <kbd><sup>&</sup><sub>7</sub></kbd><kbd><sup>*</sup><sub>8</sub></kbd> <kbd><sup>(</sup><sub>9</sub></kbd><kbd><sup>)</sup><sub>0</sub></kbd> <kbd><sup>_</sup><sub>-</sub></kbd><kbd><sup>+</sup><sub>=</sub></kbd>                 <kbd>delete</kbd>


<kbd>tab</kbd>                    <kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd><sup>{</sup><sub>[</sub></kbd> <kbd><sup>}</sup><sub>]</sub></kbd>    <kbd><sup>|</sup><sub>\</sub></kbd>   
<kbd><sup>⇪</sup> caps lock</kbd>           <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd><sup>:</sup><sub>;</sub></kbd> <kbd><sup>"</sup><sub>'</sub></kbd> <kbd><sup>↵</sup> <sub>return</sub></kbd>  
<kbd>shift                      <sup>⇧</sup></kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd><sup><sub>,</sub></sup></kbd> <kbd><sup>></sup><sub>.</sub></kbd> <kbd><sup>?</sup><sub>/</sub></kbd> <kbd><sup>⇧</sup>       shift</kbd>
<kbd><sup>⌃</sup> control</kbd> <kbd><sup>⌥ alt</sup> <sub>option</sub></kbd> <kbd>cmd  <sup>⌘</sup></kbd>                               <kbd>⌘ <sub>cmd</sub></kbd> <kbd>alt ⌥  <sub>option</sub></kbd>  <kbd>⌃ control</kbd></kbd>

(based off of my keyboard)

Answer (score 36):

<kbd>I had no idea you could even do this, but now that I know, I want to do it everywhere!!!</kbd>

<kbd>Ins</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd>

<kbd>Del</kbd> <kbd>End</kbd> <kbd>PgDn</kbd>

<kbd>↑</kbd>

<kbd>←</kbd>  <kbd>↓</kbd>   <kbd>→</kbd>

Comment: If only that were an actual key on my keyboard...

Comment: +1 for echoing my thought exactly!

Answer (score 24):

```
          I 

       am ok

     w  i t  h 

  t   h   i   s
```

Answer (score 22):

Eliminating this is an affront to Emacs users everywhere. They will then delete SO with:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>

Comment: False! There is no way there is an emacs keybinding for that without Meta, Super and/or Hyper.

Comment: @Dimension1n0 Serves you right for trying to delete the Stack Exchange flagship site! >:-(

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>If you have an older Mac keyboard (just for <kbd>[fun](/questions/tagged/fun)</kbd>, of course):</kbd>

<kbd><kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd><kbd>F13</kbd>  <kbd>F14</kbd>  <kbd>F15</kbd>   <kbd>F16</kbd>  

 <kbd>`</kbd>  <kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>5</kbd>  <kbd>6</kbd>  <kbd>7</kbd>  <kbd>8</kbd>  <kbd>9</kbd>  <kbd>0</kbd>  <kbd>-</kbd>  <kbd>=</kbd> <kbd>delete</kbd>         <kbd>help</kbd>  <kbd>home</kbd><kbd>pgup</kbd>

<kbd>tab</kbd>    <kbd>Q</kbd>  <kbd>W</kbd>  <kbd>E</kbd>  <kbd>R</kbd>  <kbd>T</kbd>  <kbd>Y</kbd>  <kbd>U</kbd>   <kbd>I</kbd>   <kbd>O</kbd>  <kbd>P</kbd>  <kbd>[</kbd>  <kbd>]</kbd>  <kbd>\</kbd>       <kbd>⌫</kbd>    <kbd>end</kbd>  <kbd>pgdn</kbd>

<kbd>caps    *</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>  <kbd>S</kbd>  <kbd>D</kbd>  <kbd>F</kbd>  <kbd>G</kbd>  <kbd>H</kbd>  <kbd>J</kbd>  <kbd>K</kbd>  <kbd>L</kbd>  <kbd>:</kbd>  <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>return</kbd>      

<kbd>shift</kbd>            <kbd>Z</kbd>  <kbd>X</kbd>  <kbd>C</kbd>  <kbd>V</kbd>  <kbd>B</kbd>  <kbd>N</kbd>  <kbd>M</kbd>  <kbd>,</kbd>  <kbd>.</kbd>   <kbd>/</kbd>    <kbd>shift</kbd>                            <kbd>▲</kbd>  

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd>                                                                                  <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd>    <kbd>◄</kbd>     <kbd>▼</kbd>    <kbd>▶</kbd>   



 <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>⏏︎</kbd>

<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> 

<kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> 

<kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> 
<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>   

<kbd>0</kbd>         <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>⏎</kbd></kbd>