# Keyboard Glyphs

Tags: support, markdown, keyboard

How are people showing keyboard "glyphs" on Super User? I looked at the Markdown help page and it didn't show anything regarding this.

Here is [an example.](https://web.archive.org/web/20110529123411/https://superuser.com/questions/257/what-new-win7-keboard-shortcuts-have-you-found-most-useful) (question has been deleted since this was asked, so an archive link is provided instead):

[image]

Comment: A very easy way to find this out would have been click the edit button on a post where you see this and look at their code.

Comment: @Jasper: sure, but I was specifically wondering if this was something implemented in stackoverflow's flavor of Markdown. Turned out it was just straight up html

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña In fact, the "magic" isn't in the html. but in the css and could have been applied to a span just as easily.

Answer (score 330, accepted):

You need to use the `<kbd>` HTML tag:

```
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
```

becomes <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

Comment: Note that these don't work in comments but appears as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

Comment: Or, now that mid 2012 these sites started being HTML5, the [w3.org recommended way](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-kbd-element) would be `<kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd></kbd>`... But yes, that is ugly here! (And yes, it's just a recommendation...)

Comment: __Hmm__ <kbd>kbd stopped working in comments</kbd>

Comment: @bobobobo HTML isn't allowed in comments :(

Comment: https://kbd.hsuan.xyz Hi, I made a tool to capture shortcuts and generate `kbd` tags.

Answer (score 69):

If you want to reference special keys such as <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>, you can use these special characters:

Mac:

- <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> <kbd>⌥</kbd> `<kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>` `<kbd>⌥</kbd>`
- <kbd>⌃ Control</kbd> <kbd>⌃</kbd> `<kbd>⌃ Control</kbd>` `<kbd>⌃</kbd>`
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>⇧</kbd> `<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>` `<kbd>⇧</kbd>`
- <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> `<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>` `<kbd>⌘</kbd>`
- <kbd>⎋ Escape</kbd> <kbd>⎋</kbd> `<kbd>⎋ Escape</kbd>` `<kbd>⎋</kbd>`
- <kbd>⇪ Caps lock</kbd> <kbd>⇪</kbd> `<kbd>⇪ Caps lock</kbd>` `<kbd>⇪</kbd>`
- <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> <kbd>⇥</kbd> `<kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd>` `<kbd>⇥</kbd>`
- <kbd>⏏︎ Eject</kbd> <kbd>⏏︎</kbd> `<kbd>⏏︎ Eject</kbd>` `<kbd>⏏︎</kbd>`
- <kbd>⌫ Delete</kbd> <kbd>⌫</kbd> `<kbd>⌫ Delete</kbd>` `<kbd>⌫</kbd>`

You can always access these symbols via Character Viewer on a Mac:

1. Edit > Emoji & Symbols <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>
2. You'll find these under the **Symbols** > **⌘ Technical Symbols** list

Answer (score 23):

[<kbd> elements are way intrusive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive) For great humor.

Comment: I wanted to vote this down for not being an answer, but I was so glad I clicked through the link. No down vote from me.

Answer (score 11):

Additionally, if you have formatting questions like that, you can look at the source of the post to see what markup was used (by clicking edit).

Answer (score 2):

In the new [Stacks Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380295/announcing-the-stacks-editor-beta-release), the shortcut Keyboard <kbd>Ctrl-'</kbd> is introduced.
Reference: https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/51
Using the new shortcut you are able to create the Keyboard Glyphs in the editor.

**Screenshot for reference:**
[image: Keyboard shortcut added - image]

**GIF for reference**:

[image: Keyboard shortcut added - gif]