# Keyboard Glyphs in comment

Tags: support, comments, markdown, keyboard-glyphs

Related to [Keyboard Glyphs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/keyboard-glyphs) question.

Is it possible in comment too or only in question and answer?

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
```

Comment: In short: no, it's not possible.