# How to set a no break in keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: support, markdown, editor, html-entities

I'm wondering if it's possible to set a keyboard shortcut reference to be no breakable

Example:

As is:

> Keyboard shortcuts are shown in menus, contextual menus and by (on Windows) pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

As wanted (automatically rather than manually):

> Keyboard shortcuts are shown in menus, contextual menus and by (on Windows) pressing
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Already tried to use

`<nobr>` HTML tag (obsolete): `<nobr><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd></nobr>`

> Keyboard shortcuts are shown in menus, contextual menus and by (on Windows) pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

CSS inline style: white-space:nowrap; `<span style:"white-space:nowrap;"><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd></span>`

> Keyboard shortcuts are shown in menus, contextual menus and by (on Windows) pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

HTML entity for no breaking spaces: `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>&nbsp;+&nbsp;<kbd>/</kbd>`

> Keyboard shortcuts are shown in menus, contextual menus and by (on Windows) pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

## Related

- [Keyboard Glyphs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/keyboard-glyphs)
- [Avoid line break between html elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19212188/1595451)

Answer (score 2):

Ugly but works:

Nest kbd tags `<kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd></kbd>`

> Keyboard shortcuts are shown in menus, contextual menus and by ( on Windows 10) pressing <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd></kbd>

(The inner elements are shown on a smaller font size so I add few characters to the original sentence)