# Markdown syntax for pseudo-tags in question/answer text?

Tags: support, tags, markdown

I like how tags are cleverly displayed in gray boxes in this question, among others:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6119/retag-request-opensource-open-source

What's the markdown syntax for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be the `<kbd>` tag:

```
<kbd>hello, world</kbd>
```

becomes

<kbd>hello, world</kbd>

It's used mainly to demonstrate keys that the reader is supposed to press, like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, etc.

Though `<kbd>` is an HTML tag, StackOverflow applies some CSS to make it look like a real button:

```
kbd {
  background:#EEEEEE none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-color:#CCCCCC #AAAAAA #888888 #BBBBBB;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px 3px 3px 1px;
  color:#000000;
  padding:2px 4px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks.  So this is just standard HTML, not markdown?  Any special CSS required to format it like the real tag rectangles?

Comment: Yes, and I've updated my answer to include it

Comment: Coolness           .

Comment: This should be added to the "Formatting reference"

Comment: Cool, I think I may have to copy and paste that into my personal CSS for help pages, I can see this making a real difference to users when suggesting they press a specified button.

Answer (score 6):

Note that, if talking about actual tags, it's better to use the new `[meta-tag:tags]` ->  [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) syntax; see [Is there some markup to post tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags) or the formatting help for details.

Answer (score 1):

Fun with <kdb> tags:  [<kbd> elements are way intrusive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive)