# Is there some markup to post tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, markdown, design

I am wondering because I was editing my profile and I though it would be nice to put the languages I know and stuff like tags.

Is it possible to post a tag? If it's not, do you think it's possible to implement on the profile?

For example:

```
[c#]
```

Would generate

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

With tag formatting and link...

Comment: I take it you weren't keen on my idea of inserting images.

Comment: @Robert: Your idea is not totally bad, but it's a lot of work. Would be nice to have this feature which could be used more easily. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Hmm. Why isn't this in `[faq]`?

Comment: Does this work in tag wiki excerpts too? Ie. can I refer to another tag from within that tag description?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

We're now supporting the following syntax.

```
[tag:tag-name]
&
[meta-tag:tag-name]
```

Examples:

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)
[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

This is done on post submission*, and for now isn't reflected in the editor preview.  Note that we aren't pulling in styling from the "parent" site either, though that may change in the future.

Furthermore, the `meta-tag` syntax is only available on meta sites.  `tag` naturally works everywhere.

<sub>*Which means it only applies to new and/or newly editted posts.</sub>

Comment: Nice. Do these work in comments as well? Here's a test: [tag:bug] [tag:markdown] - apparently not.

Comment: Cool!! It's perfect. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: :s/post.tag/post-text

Comment: On my meta site, can I link to tags on the parent site?

Comment: @Alex Currently not. I'm thinking I'll make a request for that, though.

Comment: @Kevin, How about allow this in the tag-wikis also so we can reference tags?

Comment: @Lance - its allowed in the tag wiki "body" but not the excerpt.  This is [status-by-design], at least for now.

Comment: @Kevin, yes, but that makes it mostly useless, the excerpt is what people mostly see.

Comment: Can this be added to the advanced formatting documentation, at least on Meta? I never knew this existed until I saw it in somebody's post, and since it's not shown in the preview, it was even harder to know how to get it to show up.

Comment: Does this affect syntax highlighting? What I've heard is that language tags on the *question* will affect which language the code-highlighter looks for.

Comment: @Justin - the [tag:blah] markdown doesn't affect syntax highlighting in any way.

Answer (score 5):

I think your best bet is to insert an image, like this:

[image]

If you hover over it, you will notice that it actually has a link.

**Here's how I did it:**

```
I think your best bet is to insert an image, like this:

[![alt text][1]][2]

If you hover over it, you will notice that it actually has a link.  

**Here's how I did it:**

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlkdT.png
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/C%23
```

Comment: Postception. :P

Answer (score 4):

Now that this has been implemented, I wonder [why](/questions/tagged/why) people would use this.

Like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/208652/firefox-addon-to-search-a-page-with-regex) kind of bothers me:

[image: Noooo!]

Comment: I've seen many times a question for `x` and answers for `y`, `z` with a very clear question. And I've experienced it as well. That's why I got a bit bored from SO. The downvotes I give are mostly for these cases. That's why I gave so much emphasis.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that Super User post was yours too! Wow, you really like those tags...

Comment: I don't think I'd ever use them in a normal post, but I use them in meta posts to refer to the actual tags themselves ( [example](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252/please-merge-some-tags/254#254) )

Comment: I personally don't see what's wrong with the image in your post. In fact, I find it more expressive & resourceful. Mind giving some insight into why you feel that image is bothersome?

Comment: @Vince, in the question text Firefox is just a name for me (which, as an aside, should be written with an uppercase F, which the tag does not). And a very well known name at that; nobody needs the additional information that the tags gives on hover, I think (and if one does: that's where the tags are for below the question text). So, I feel it's just abused for formatting, like some abuse backticks to write `Firefox`. No one would write Firefox that way when using pen and paper. Of course, the very same applies to the "why" in my answer text.