# Link embedded images to their URL

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images, uploader

When uploading an image, the markdown inserted should be changed from

```
![alt text][1]
```

..to..

```
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwxyz.png">![alt text][1]</a>
```

This will be most helpful when images are wider than 630px, allowing the viewer to remove the distortion inherent in scaled images.

Answer (score 10):

While it would be nice if it was done automatically, it's easy to link the image to itself:

```
[![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwxyz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwxyz.png)
```

Answer (score 5):

Some thoughts if this gets implemented:

- For the data dumps, maybe rewriting the images needs to be done when generating the HTML, not in the Markdown code itself? (Just like when rendering bare URLs into clickable links [with a full title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/69483#69483), or when [using `[tag:tag-name]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482).)
- Some users [very nicely link cropped images](https://superuser.com/questions/243413/bypass-bios-password-set-by-faulty-toshiba-firmware-on-satellite-a55-s1065-laptop) to full versions, or link images to web pages. It would be nice if that is still possible. (So, automatic linking should be smart to detect that.)
- Maybe the (bottom) link border can be removed/changed in the CSS?
- Maybe large images can be shown in a smaller size right away? Like if *the height* exceeds some limit, then set it:

  ```
  <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx.png">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx.png" 
      height="100" alt="alt text" title="Click to enlarge"></a>
  ```

  [image: Image upload dialog]

  Or better yet: truly resize the image, as requested in [Embed smaller version of images from imgur.com to reduce traffic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107927/embed-smaller-version-of-images-from-imgur-com-to-reduce-traffic).
- Maybe [the *alt text*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74048/encourage-people-to-use-alt-text) and optional *title* can be prompted for as well? Too many images simply have the default "alt text", which is not helping the visually impaired. And sane browsers will not display the *alt text* in a tooltip, so asking for both *alt text* and optional *title* might be nice?

  ```
  [![alt text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx.png "Title")
  ```

  In the alternative syntax, using the very same `[x]` reference twice, is currently automatically changed into two different `[x]` and `[y]` references when adding a new link or image using the toolbar. Hence when really changing the Markdown text source (rather than when generating the HTML, which I'd vote for), then I guess two references need to be inserted when using the alternative syntax:

  ```
  [![alt text][1]][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx.png "Title"
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx.png "Title"
  ```

Answer (score 2):

This has been implemented (a long, long time ago). The old editor does this:

[image]

while the [new Stacks editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/295232) does it more like the [top-voted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68436/295232):

[image]

Both options offer the ability to view images full-screen.

Comment: Also, if you want to edit the size of the image embedded in the post (using [Imgur's built-in resizing options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253405/1478931)) while still linking to the full-size image, you can do so by editing the first URL – e.g. `[![I added the letter m to this URL ->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cV4jm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cV4j.png)`. (This is slightly more inconvenient to do when using "footnote-style" link formatting, which is the old editor's default link formatting style.)