# How do I set the size of a picture in my question post?

Tags: discussion, images

The picture I uploaded is too large... Is there a way to limit the size (width & height)?

Answer (score 103):

If you are using the native Stack Overflow imgur service (eg. clicking the little icon for adding an image in the toolbar), you can just append an `s` or `m` or `l` (for small/medium/large) at the end of the URL, before the file extension.

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXY0J.jpg
```

[image: demonstration image]

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXY0Jm.jpg
```

[image: demonstration image]

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXY0Js.jpg
```

[image: demonstration image]

You could link to the full-size image if you want, too.

Comment: Yup. This. And you *should* be using the provided image hosting anyway, since that helps to keep down image rot.

Comment: Even adding `l` for "large" is actually useful to save bandwidth: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8IlR6.jpg vs http://i.stack.imgur.com/8IlR6l.jpg Thinking about it, maybe Stack Exchange should do that by default.

Comment: @Arjan Then if we wanted to post a giant picture of a unicorn, how would we do it? We'd need a new `h` suffix for "huge".

Comment: Or remove the `l`, @Cody, if you'd know how the image insert works. Alternatively, Stack Exchange could post-process the pre-cooked HTML, to only add the `l` on the regular site, but I guess that's a no go. (In the regular site, the posts are limited to 660px, and imgur's "large" is 640px. So, we're 20px short if Stack Exchange would always add the `l` for the regular site only. But again: that needs post-processing of the cached HTML. On mobile, there's only `max-width: 90%` for images, so indeed image width could exceed imgur's 640px.)

Comment: It didn't work for me while I was creating the question. But after posting the question, I could edit and the feature worked fine.

Answer (score 33):

You can use `<img>` tag to place the image and control its size:

```html
<img src="{link to image}" width="{width}" height="{height}" />
```

Optionally, you can also leave out either `height` or `width` (but not both) to proportionally set the other value.

```html
<img src="{link to image}" width="{width}" />
```

---

#### Examples

Resized to 200 by 200 in `<img>`:

[image]

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" width="200" />
```

Resized to 150 by 150 in `<img>`:

[image]

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" width="150" />
```

Original image, 100 by 100 pixels.

[image]

```
![](https://via.placeholder.com/100)
```

Resized to 50 by 50 in `<img>`:

[image]

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" width="50" />
```

Resized to 25 by 25 in `<img>`:

[image]

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" width="25" />
```

Resized to 10 by 10 in `<img>`:

[image]

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" width="10" />
```

Comment: True, but note that the mobile theme uses `max-width: 90%` which might yield odd results when setting both `width` and `height`. Also, this should not be used to resize huge images (see [Please do something to encourage people to scale down their giant heavyweight photos](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/please-do-something-to-encourage-people-to-scale-down-their-giant-heavyweight-ph).)

Comment: if using `<img ` it may be good to use `alt=" ... "` for accessibility as well

Comment: @nonopolarity Unfortunately you cannot use `<img />` inside a StackExchange answer post with both `width=""` and `alt=""` at the same time, I don't know if that's a bug or not.

Answer (score -3):

At the moment picture resize feature is not available. You have to do it manually by local software.