# Why are large images less high quality?

Tags: support, design, images

It may just be me, but when I compare these images, the one with no size change looks much better:

No size change:

[image]

Size change (l):

[image]

Size change (img tag):

[image]

Why does the `img` tag look so much better than the `l` extension to me?

Comment: Because your browser is better at resizing things than Imgur is. That "large" image that Imgur generated (which only actually shaves off 2 pixels from the width and height of the original image) cuts off a whole 13KB from the image's size. Lots of compression and quality loss by using that image.

Comment: @animuson Ahh. Is there a way to resize that looks good on bigger displays, without the img tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As animuson said, using the imgur options l,m,s invokes aggressive image compression in addition to resizing. If this is not desirable, the options are:

1. Do nothing, let the image be as large as the website allows (so it will be browser-resized to the width of the post area).
2. Use `<img src=" " width=" ">` tag.
3. Resize the image yourself prior to posting.

Comment: As for 1 and 2, see also [Please do something to encourage people to scale down their giant heavyweight photos](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/) and [Can automatic loading of giant images be solved?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163563/)

Answer (score 1):

Because setting a width to img tag **doesn't resize** the image (unless the specified width is greater then th width of actual image), but just *scales*  it, to *fit* the frame in pixels you want. However this doesn't change the image size in pixels. You can see it by posting (or embedding elsewhere; that's not SE-related) a large image using `<img src="src-there" width="some-small-width">` and then zooming in or dragging the image to your desktop. You'll see the image doesn't get pixelated unless you reach the full size by zooming.

Imgur **actually resizes** the image, i.e. decreases the size in pixels.