# Embed smaller version of images from imgur.com to reduce traffic

Tags: feature-request, images, imgur

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please do something to encourage people to scale down their giant heavyweight photos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/please-do-something-to-encourage-people-to-scale-down-their-giant-heavyweight-pho)

This is a follow-up to [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101439/132564) that currently has 25 upvotes and has been discussed [on Bicycles meta](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/q/443/628) and [on DIY meta](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/369/807) (the two sites I believe benefit the most from this improvement) and now it looks like a good for all solution is clear.

Many users upload images right from their gazillion megapixel cameras to imgur.com and we have giant super hi-res images to just show something which fits into a much smaller image. So the net result is that all users have to download 700 kilobyte images on page load even if they don't need a hi-res version of each image.

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/please-do-something-to-encourage-people-to-scale-down-their-giant-heavyweight-pho/101446#101446) by [user Jeremy Banks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/134300/jeremy-banks) suggests the following. For each image on imgur.com a downscaled version can be requested - imgur.com will render it on itself. For each image path `https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImageCode.jpg` the same path with `l` before dot - `https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImageCodel.jpg` - will retrieve a downscaled version of the image.

So could you please implement the following: when I insert an image with `![description][X]` markdown pattern show the downscaled version of the image which has a link to the full-size version underneath (I mean usual stuff when one can click on the image and see a hi-res version)?