# Automatically resize uploaded images

Tags: feature-request, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thumbnail image on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74312/thumbnail-image-on-stack-overflow)
>   [Embed smaller version of images from imgur.com to reduce traffic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107927/embed-smaller-version-of-images-from-imgur-com-to-reduce-traffic)

Could large images of more then 640 pixels wide automatically be resized to reduce loading time and band width use? Not that I have a prehistoric internet connection here, but sometimes pages seem to need unnecessary time to load fully.

I just resized the image [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10178173/757830) from 179 kb down to 32 kb using a 15% compression rate. I think that is already worth it, although there have been much bigger downsizes in the past.

This feature then propably should/could be combined with [automatically linking the embedded image to its full-size URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68435/162538), and uploading an image then would result in the following post addition:

```
[![enter image description here][2]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSBxw.gif "View <image title> full sized"
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXmBA.jpg "<Image title>"
```

#### Update:

I now understand from [this assumed duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74312/162538) that images áre resized already, but that post authors have to do some changes themselves. Could it then be automated to add the already resized image (that with the `l` suffix):

```
[![enter image description here][2]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSBxw.gif "View <image title> full sized"
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSBxwl.jpg "<Image title>"
```

Comment: Ugh! I hate it when they post huge images. Especially when 40% or more of the image is *blank* and so it's big and useless. I'd also suggest this guideline: ***Crop your image** to include only the relevant part before you upload it.*

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't handle the image uploading stuff. Imgur does, so you're stuck with what Imgur provides (which is outlined in the duplicated question).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a moderator on a site where we use large images (schematics) frequently, I think it's very important  that the original-sized image should still be accessible in some way or another.  Image resizing algorithms are pretty good, but it can be painful to read poorly-downsized text.

I'd be all over a request to change the Markdown generated by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> from

```
![enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0BxW.png"<Image title>"
```

to

```
[![enter image description here][1]][2]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0BxW.png"<Image title>"
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0BxWm.png"Click for full-size version of <Image title>"
```

whenever a >640px wide image was uploaded.  This would display the imgur-resized image inline, and the full-size would be linked in directly.

Comment: but the upload won't even let me upload images over 2MB *at all*.