# Full resolution option for embedded pictures?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images

Maybe this has already been addressed.  I searched around here but maybe I'm searching for the wrong keywords.

I'd like to see a built in "click through" option that would automatically open an embedded picture that ends up on https://i.stack.imgur.com.

Currently, high resolution pictures end up getting embedded into the frame of the question making them difficult to discern unless you copy the image location and then paste it into a new browser tab.  At that point you can get a full resolution from the direct link.

Has this been discussed before?  Is it a difficult undertaking for the SE staff to offer an option where if you click on the image it automatically opens the direct link in a new tab or like other forums I see show a `"This image has been resized.  Click the bar to view the full image.  The original image is sized xxxx by yyyy"`?

EDIT: well now I see this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129488/219991 but while it was the accepted answer it doesn't appear to be implemented.

Comment: Why not just insert the image, leaving `![...][1]` and then changing that to `[![...][1]][1]`? That would link to the full-resolution image.

Comment: @Werner - the issue for me isn't if there's a workaround...it was more of a "can it be automated" thing by the built in uploader.

Comment: @Werner I do that.  It's a pain, but the primary problem is that newer or less technically inclined users don't know about it, and don't do it, so that either leaves the editors doing a lot of manual work that could be scripted, or (more often), it just doesn't get done.

Comment: @Thomas any chance to get a preview of what the team got planned?

Comment: Hey @ShadowWizard — there's nothing *planned* just yet, but I'm going to bring up the change in the markdown generated by the insert image feature (essentially automating what Werner suggested in his post). I'll update the status here if / when a decision is made one way or another.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco cheers, in case you missed it, [there's also an older answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129488/152859) with the same code and bit more.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowWizard! That other request is also about embedding smaller thumbnails rather than leaving the browser to resize the full picture (comparatively, the current request is just about adding a clickthrough to the picture). I anticipate that embedding smaller thumbnails is a more complex change (especially because a given size doesn't necessarily make sense on both the mobile and regular versions of the site). We'll probably talk about both requests, but it's possible one will be do-able and not the other.

Comment: Hey there. Just a quick update that we are looking into auto-inserting a link to the image when its uploaded using our image uploader.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco - thank you sir!

Comment: This is now live! From now on, the image uploader automatically wraps images in a link to themselves. [Balpha](http://stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) is to thank for this change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As an interim measure, I've written [a userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/4943/view-full-image-sizes) that makes images link to their original/full sizes.

You can install the current version from [here](https://github.com/Elusive138/SEImageExpander/raw/master/SEImageExpander.user.js).

Currently tested on Firefox/Greasemonkey. It *should* work on Chrome, but I've lost track on the current way to install userscripts there.

Comment: You sir...are the man!  Thank you!  Personally, I still think this should be by design on the site...but this works for at least those of us bothered enough to track this down!