# Click-to-zoom feature for images

Tags: feature-request, images

What would you think of adding a click-to-zoom feature to images by default? It could look like [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) or [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/). **This really is something different from the post that was suggested as a duplicate:** that posts requests a link to the image, while I'd like to see a pop-up *on SE*.

Now, I'm doing this all the time: `[![image description][1]][1]` But that links to the image directly and that doesn't look so neat.

It's really annoying to have images scaled down so that they aren't well readable anymore, and having to right-click, copy image URL, open new tab, paste, enter in order to see the full size image.

So, what would you think of adding a click-to-zoom feature to images by default?

[image]

Comment: And also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68435/152859

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd **actually not**, those feature-requests just request links to the image, while I'd like to see a zoomed image _on SE_. See the two links I gave (lightbox and fancybox)

Comment: I'm kinda against this. Pictures *should not* be first class citizens and therefor should not get a great treatment, they should be used *rarely*. The people with screenreaders will thank you.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby I guess that's different on other sites. For example, on [electronics.se], we nearly always ask for a schematic. It's just annoying if the image is then too small to be able to read it properly. Why exactly shouldn't this be added? It doesn't conflict with any existing feature.

Comment: @Bart this question actually is a specific idea that answers the question there. Would it be possible to convert it to an answer, or should I do that myself?

Comment: @CamilStaps There is no convert question to answer option. If you think this answers something, you can make it an answer yourself.

Comment: @Bart thanks, did that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179315/205264

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you want, but it comes close (it is especially useful on sites like Gardening and Photography where huge photos are common):

Try [my thumbnail uploader script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3507/thumbnail-uploader). It lets you upload images with an option for thumbnailing.