# Tags don't render in preview

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, markdown-preview

The `[tag:tagname]` syntax is [now supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482) in the post, but the preview doesn't recognize them and show them as plain text (i.e. instead of [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown), it is simply displayed as [tag:markdown] ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now implemented:

[image: tags in wmd preview]

Answer (score 5):

I wanted the visual feedback, so I went ahead and created a userscript for the time being that hooks into the preview code to render the tags. It also tries to address [this style issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70423/150235) by adding in a new style rule on meta sites.

The previewed tags will also show the new tag bubbles so you can verify you linked to the correct tag. If you're linking to a main site tag from a meta though, there's currently [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74349/tag-bubbles-on-metas-point-to-meta-tags-not-parent-tags) to contend with, which might make that a little less effective at the moment.

> Get the Script: **[Install](https://github.com/tms/StackExchangeTests/raw/master/TagPreview.user.js)** – **[Source](https://github.com/tms/StackExchangeTests/blob/master/TagPreview.user.js)**

Here's a screenshot of some of different tags being rendered in the preview box on various metas:

[image: Preview of rendered tag Markdown]

Comment: +1 nice job -- although I'm afraid it's a little bit of wasted efforts; this is in the short-term queue already :) Also, a little but report: As you can see in the source of this very question, it doesn't honor the code syntax.

Comment: @balpha Hahah, well, that's better anyway :) Argh, you're right...that's why I leave the real feature-making up to you guys, heh. I'll see if there's anything that can be easily done about that this late in the processing, for the sake of correctness.

Answer (score 2):

From the post you linked to...

> This is done on post submission*, **and for now isn't reflected in the editor preview**.

(emphasis mine)