# Special styled tags are not styled correctly in the post body

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, markdown

For example, if a tag has a red background and white text it will retain the black text if used in the post body. This makes it impossible to read.

I'm hoping this is not [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: I feel like this is a dupe, but I can't find it.

Comment: not by-design, I talked to Kev about it the other day. It is a fairly large scale change so it will have to wait a few more days

Comment: Is this a recent bug? At home last night, your `[status-bydesign]` was white on red, but here at work it's black on red.

Comment: @Jon I see white on red, but if I mouse over it it's red on grey instead of white on grey. Maybe he's done fixing part of it?

Comment: @Michael: Hovering over I saw red on grey yesterday, just like it is now. Possible caching issue for me? I'll dump my cache at home tonight and have another look.

Comment: @rchern It was tangentially mentioned [in the comments of this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482), but never made as a post-level report.

Comment: Hmmm... it still shows white on red for me at home. WinXP + FF 3.6.12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a fairly time consuming change (lots of little CSS tweaks to test in a bunch of browsers), and other issues* are taking up my time right now.

Will probably get around to this sometime shortly after Thanksgiving.

<sub>*And that mythical beast, "time off" is coming up as well.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a real answer, but here's a screen cap of what I see on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/47640#47640) from my work machine (Win7 + FF 3.6.12) after I edited in the tag syntax yesterday. Totally bizarre.

[image]

Comment: `.moderator-tag:visited` has `color: #FFFFFF;` and is not less specific than the selector that defines the wrong colour, which is why you see some in white. The others will turns to white if you click them and go back to the post.

Comment: @Tim: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh maybe that's why they all show up in white for me at home.

Comment: Seems likely, yeah. :) The rest are wonky because `.post-text a` is more specific than `.moderator-tag`...hopefully that'll be resolved soon. It started bugging me so much I wrote a userstyle for myself to change it, heh.