# Tag bubbles on metas point to meta tags, not parent tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, tag-bubble

See [this answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/top-tags-requiring-a-tag-wiki/1595#1595): all the "rss" and "help us edit this wiki" (and possibly the subscribe link too?) point to the meta site -- whereas a click on the link proper goes to the parent site.

#### Reproducible on MSO: [featured](/questions/tagged/featured).

The tag link points to Stack Overflow, where it's pointless, but the bubble fetches links and excerpt from Meta Stack Overflow. Compare with the MSO tag [featured](/questions/tagged/featured).

Additionally, the SO tag becomes red, although it has no special meaning there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these will be fixed in the next build.

There is no tag menu anymore if it's not a tag on *this* site, and the parent-site tags won't get extra styling anymore.

Note that the second point will require the post to be re-rendered (i.e. edited).

Comment: Will `[tag:foo]` expressions on metas still be rendered as links to the foo tag on the parent site?

Comment: Your comment previously said they'll still be rendered as tags (just no red and no menu) -- has that changed?

Comment: @badp: No, but since you removed your question, I removed my answer :) The rendering will look precisely as it already does in the WMD preview.