# Tags not rendered in preview while editing Help Center pages

Tags: bug, tags, moderator-tools, help-center, markdown-preview

Moderators are able to edit the Help Center page [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) on their site. This uses the standard post editor, but it [does not render tag links (e.g. `[tag:support]`) in the preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78401/295232). Other types of rendering, e.g. regular links, do work in the preview. And as you can see in the first link, the tag links *are* rendered in the article itself.

[image]

It makes no difference if I use `[meta-tag:support]` instead (Meta Stack Exchange is its own meta, so that syntax works), and I can reproduce it on other sites as well.