# Shortcut to tag-wiki as hyperlink

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki

**Feature-Request**

- in order to increase the usability of a Stack Overflow site by having more hyperlinks

  - and make it easier for an "author of a page" to create hyperlinks
- as a stackoverflow-reader

  - and stackoverflow-writer
- I want a formatting shortcut for to a link a [tag-wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tag-wiki/info)

currently I have to write something like [ tag-wiki ] (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tag-wiki/info) if I want to link to tag-wiki.

I would propose this syntax [tag-wiki][] meaning that there are predefined references to the tag.

Comment: update: sombody edited one of my stackoverflow artikels with somthink like this [tag:tag-wiki] this workes with stckoverflow.com but not with meta.stackoverflow.com. 
Could you add this topic to the onlinehelp :-)

Comment: what do you mean by "reader" and "writer"? Questioner and answerer?

Comment: are you looking for [this documentation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482)? (It is hard to find, no question.)

Comment: @peter: the original request was written in bdd-specification style that contains "In Order To" + expectedBenefit + "As A" + NameOfRoleWhoWouldBenefit + "I Want" + feature. You translated my bdd-style request back into simple english. "Reader" and "Writer" where my role as a stackoverflow user.

Comment: @Popular Demand: Yes i didn-t find the that documentation. I was asking if you can add this info to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help where i can find it if i click on the edit-help button ?