# The "without" Tag

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-block-request

Currently, there are [25 questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/without) that have [without](/questions/tagged/without) as one of their tags. A sample of some of these questions' titles are as follows:

- [Twitter Oauth via PHP WITHOUT cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849415/twitter-oauth-via-php-without-curl)
- [Marquee without Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197994/marquee-without-space)
- [Protect Windows folder without encrypting the contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414525/protect-windows-folder-without-encrypting-the-contents)

It seems like the only way that these questions are related to one another is by chance -- it's not inherently descriptive at all. Could we get rid of this (arguably useless) tag? Does it add any value that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @KennyTM Didn't even realize you could do "`[tag:`..."

Comment: It's a relatively new feature that was implemented a couple weeks ago. You can read up more about it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482), Donut. ♪

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when people don't realize tags can't contain spaces; for example, [Twitter Oauth via PHP WITHOUT cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849415/twitter-oauth-via-php-without-curl) was almost certainly tagged "without curl", which turns into [without](/questions/tagged/without) [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) -- the author meant to tag it something like [without-curl](/questions/tagged/without-curl). I think the policy in the past has been to blacklist words like "without" that only come up in these situations

Comment: Gotcha... so who does the "blacklisting"? And do you agree that this is an appropriate case for doing so?

Comment: @Donut A developer needs to do it. This probably is a good case for it; they'll see your post and comment I imagine

Comment: Gotcha. Sounds good.

Comment: Actually, I think what happens now is that they've raised the bar for creating new tags, such that all we have to do to blacklist it for about 95% of all users is remove all uses of the tag.  Then it will be deleted (iirc at midnight utc) and de facto blacklisted.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]