# How do we present Tags in the editor?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, editor

What do we write in the editor, to present a `Tag`?
I tried searching and all i found was questions about Tag Editing in SO.

Comment: The post about it is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markdown you're looking for is:

```
[tag:mytag]
```

Comment: Thanks Kev :-) Exactly what i was looking for. Nice cat by the way, i have 2 running around my apartment now :-)