# Linking to tags in about me section

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

How can we link to tags in our about me section like [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas) did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here:

[Is there some markup to post tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482)

basically, use:

```
[tag:tag-name]
```

example: [support](/questions/tagged/support)

(Although I'm not sure how he did the pop-out-on-hover work, as it doesn't seem to work here...)

Comment: I just tried it on both meta and SO, and on SO, the pop-out works, on meta not, so it must be something that can be enabled per site.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `[tag:tag-name]`, where tag-name is the name of the tag.
The preview shown after the "About Me" text field will show it as `[tag:tag-name]`, but it will be correctly displayed as [tag-name](/questions/tagged/tag-name), once saved.