# How do you tag tags on MSO in a comment?

Tags: discussion, tags

I tried to mention a tag in a comment by writing "[tag: tagname]" (without the space), and it pointed to a non-existent tag on SO.  I was trying to point to a tag on MSO.  Is there different syntax to do that?

Comment: FYI - this isn't specific to MSO.  All per-site metas follow the same syntax.

Comment: What would be interesting to know is will this syntax change for the new MSE when MSO splits off next month.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66965/147423

Comment: @psubsee2003: Given the gradual migration strategy they're planning, I don't see how they _could_ change it without causing massive breakage of existing posts. The new MSO will, presumably, have the same syntax as all other per-site metas (i.e. the same as we have here on "old MSO" now), while the new MSE (which will inherit posts from here) will need to retain the old MSO syntax to avoid breaking old posts.

Answer (score 5):

Just do `[meta-tag:discussion]`

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

For mod-only tags, it will update color automatically

`[meta-tag:status-bydesign]` yields [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), alternatively [declined-because-jeff-says-so](/questions/tagged/declined-because-jeff-says-so)

Comment: Note: For comments, it doesn't appear to actually look like a tag if you do `[meta-tag:discussion]`, see my [Formatting Sandbox post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/201951#201951). It does appear to link to what you'd expect though.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
[meta-tag:tagname]
```

Result:
[tagname](/questions/tagged/tagname)