# HTML special characters in html-type titles in Atom feed need to be double-escaped

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed

In the Atom feed, any HTML special characters need to be double-encoded.

For example, this item appeared in an Atom feed recently: [<kbd> elements are way intrusive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive)

In the Atom feed the title was encoded as:

```
<title type="html">&lt;kbd&gt; elements are way intrusive</title>
```

This actually needs to be double-encoded, i.e.:

```
<title type="html">&amp;lt;kbd&amp;gt; elements are way intrusive</title>
```

On Google Reader and on Firefox, it thought an actual `kbd` tag was there, and in both cases it was stripped out (so the title actually read "elements are way intrusive").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternately, SO could probably just use [`type="text"`](http://atompub.org/rfc4287.html#rfc.section.3.1.1) for the titles... AFAIK, the site doesn't allow HTML in them anyway!

Comment: ok, I switched to `type="text"` for the titles