# How can I format as keyboard keys?

Tags: support, markdown, editing-help

Some answers contain characters that look like keyboard keys. They look like

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>

What markup do I need to add to make `Ctrl` and `E` look like actual keys?
That's not mentioned in the formatting help.

Comment: +1 for adding this to the formatting help (rather than having needed Google to come up with this page).

Comment: I like, when question marked as duplicate has more votes, then original one :-D

Comment: Oh wow, my question got closed as a duplicate ... seven *years* after asking it! I wonder if there's a badge for that?

Comment: Related: [Castle building](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1974)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36427/how-do-you-add-those-keyboard-icons-to-your-post/

Answer (score 531, accepted):

Use the `<kbd>` tag. For example, write `<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>` for it to display as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

After this answer was accepted, the `<kbd>` tag was disabled on Meta. It then still worked on SO, SF and SU. Meanwhile it has been enabled on Meta again as well.

Comment: Is there a correct word to use for arrow keys? eg `Right` or `Right arrow` or `→`?

Comment: @IanVaughan use the "right arrow" :))

Comment: Does this work in comments<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 78):

Use the `kbd` tag:

```
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
```

The rendered output would look like this:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>