# How do you add those keyboard icons to your post?

Tags: support, keyboard-glyphs

In answers to Emacs-related questions, I often see key sequences displayed as a cool keyboard key icon wrapping the keystrokes.  [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100166/making-sense-out-of-emacs-completion-mode-choices/2105560#2105560):

[image: keyboard glyphs in a post]

How does one generate these?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/keyboard-glyphs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example

```
<KBD>e.g.</KBD>
```

*[See also.](https://www.w3schools.in/html-tutorial/phrase-tags/#Keyboard_Tag)*

Comment: I'm affraid your link is deprecated.

Comment: @merours link has been fixed