# unable to locate in keyboard help how to show Windows Logo key everywhere and keyboard keys in comments

Tags: support, editing-help

Windings font 0xFF is the "Windows Logo Key".

however, because of font mapping, it *appears* that simply pasting it from *Character Map* is not a solution.

For other keys, in questions, i can use **kbd** in SO but not in meta SO as per this meta [article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26207/how-can-i-format-as-keyboard-keys).

However, in SO comments, **kbd** does not work.

Comment: It is probably not supported in comments. Is it really such an issue to simply type "the windows key"?

Comment: I'm not sure about you, but I've never actually seen someone use the Windows logo for explaining the key. They always just use the word "Windows" formatted as a key like anything else.

Comment: In his defense it appears that the Command key on [Apple.SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62963/defaultkeybinding-hex-code-for-mls-start-dictation-command) is supported.

Comment: @ Oded: yes and no.  imho, it's *likely* always better to use a glyph when that glyph is for all intents and purporses universally recognized.  YMMV

Comment: @ Oded: perhaps this should have been two separate questions: one about the *Windows Logo* key *everywhere*, i.e., not only in comments, and the other about **kbd** not working in comments.

Comment: Unless you want to play jokes, I'd [not use the Wingdings character for that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_(Unicode)#Example_code_point_U.2BF8FF). (Screen capture [on a Mac](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PELoZ.png).) Also, @sixlettervariables, even Apple doesn't rely on those symbols [on its website](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343).

Comment: The Meta post you linked to was very much outdated.

Comment: @Arjan: I was being a bit tongue in cheek, but yeah images are a reliable means of avoiding font issues.

Comment: FWIW, i'm still working on this when i can steal some time from other projects ... today, while experimenting manually, i discovered that `WinLogo` + `1`, `2`, ... , `9`, `0` respectively open or activate the window associated with the first, second, ... , ninth, tenth taskbar shortcut that one finds to the right of the taskbar `Start` control; of course, if there are only say eight icons, then `WinLogo`+`9` and `WinLogo`+`0` have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

`<kbd>` isn't supposed to work in comments. Comments use mini-Markdown, where it's not supported. You'll have to settle for `inline code` or **bold** to represent keys (I prefer bold because it stands out more and inline code improperly represents it semantically).

As far as the Windows logo, it doesn't appear that there is a Unicode character that represents it, for whatever reason (I can guess why but those are just guesses, my primary guess being trademarking).

Comment: Apple's Command-key symbol is the Unicode symbol U+2318 Place of Interest ⌘. You can use **`bold code`** in comments for keys.

Comment: No Windows logo on http://copypastecharacter.com/symbols either, though the Apple symbol is listed there, when viewed from a Mac (together with a keyboard symbol, between the Music Sharp Sign and the Eject Symbol; just not there when viewed in Internet Explorer). This  probably won't render as an Apple symbol on any computer except on a Mac. Ah, [indeed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AA5mj.png).