# Formatting help needs to show how to do keyboard key markdown

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editing-help, keyboard-glyphs

Related to:

[How can I format as keyboard keys?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26207/how-can-i-format-as-keyboard-keys)

The markdown editing help page, here for example: https://superuser.com/editing-help , does not include this example.

Comment: It kind of does, in the "Inline HTML" example :P, but also in the linked list of supported HTML tags.

Comment: I've been around here a long time and must have missed that in the online help.  I think that mavhing it called out more prominently would be an improvement.