# Could the <kbd> tag be added to the editing help?

Tags: feature-request, editor, help, kbd

I happen to like the `<kbd>` tag for showing when keys should be pressed, but I can never remember it on the very few occasions that it would actually be useful. Having it in the help file would mean that I don't need to find another question that has the tag in use, and try to copy it.

I know that [some people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974) do crazy things with this tag, but in general I think that it is useful.

Comment: Be careful. If it was widely publicised we'd have the same situation on the other sites that we have here on meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/23571#23571

Comment: @ChrisF: You _could_ have that problem, but I doubt that you really would. That thread was a special I think, as per the comment on this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/23571#23571

Comment: It's in the FAQ along with the other tags SOFU allows: [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user)
And that FAQ topic is *already* linked to from Editing Help.

Comment: I laugh uncontrollably every time I see Pesto's castle creation.  But, this would definitely be of use on Super User.

Comment: I can't see it :(

Comment: I feel like this should be [meta-tag:status-nobody-seems-to-care]...

Comment: Related: [Key equivalent for <kbd></kbd>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102841/key-equivalent-for-kbd-kbd)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to [this Help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help), it is currently mentioned:

> **Inline HTML**
>
> If you need to do something that Markdown can't handle, use HTML. Note that [we only support a very strict subset of HTML!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed)
>
> `To reboot your computer, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>.`

This is not very explicit, though, and can not easily be found when you don't remember the tag to begin with. Adding an additional sentence along the lines of "*Highlight (keyboard) buttons by enclosing them with the <kbd> and </kbd> tags.*" would improve that.

The tag is also mentioned in the linked list of allowed HTML tags.

The ["new" editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor) (which you can opt into through the Settings on your profile) adds a drop-down menu through which you can access some of the markup tags (super/subscript, spoiler, meta, and keyboard (and the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> for that last option)).

[This script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-superscript-and-subscript-markup-shortcuts) will add similar functions to the toolbar of the old editor, as well.

Comment: This is good. But is there any chance of the keyboard tags `<kbd></kbd>` being integrated into Markdown? How? I dunno. Maybe a combo short tag of `_*` followed by `*_`? Or how about braces like this `{`/`}`?  An idea?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 That would probably involve updating the Markdown API (and/or 'renderers'; I'm not sure about the right terminology), and even customized functions (like they have done with [tag:], for example). Since we already have easy access to the tag as it is, I don't believe such a feature would be seriously considered.