# How do I insert the images of keys in Stack Overflow or Super User?

Tags: discussion, keyboard-shortcuts

Some of the questions / answers here have cool images of a key to press, like `Esc`, but it looks like a key.

How do I do that? I cannot see it documented in the editing FAQ or in https://superuser.com/editing-help or in the [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) documentation.

---

**Update**:

With the answers below, this should do it: `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

And it does!

It also seems that [the request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36785/could-the-kbd-tag-be-added-to-the-stackoverflow-editing-help) to add this to the documentation has not yet been completed.

Comment: For any post, even if there's not been any edit yet: see [http://superuser.com/posts/<id>/revisions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/48939/revisions) and then click "view source".

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in the comments... <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Answer (score 27):

```
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
```

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

It's `<kbd>` and `</kbd>`.

Comment: Now that I have the code of <kbd> I search and I think it still needs to be added per this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36785/could-the-kbd-tag-be-added-to-the-stackoverflow-editing-help

Comment: Doesn't work in comments, unfortunately...