# Key stroke combination markdown?

Tags: support, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard Glyphs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/keyboard-glyphs)

I got an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/211606/capturing-a-window-image-or-taking-a-screen-shot-in-a-windows-xp-virtual-machine/211610#211610) with some cool keystroke formatting, but I don't see how to do it on the [markdown reference](https://superuser.com/editing-help), or the [more detailed markdown reference](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) -- maybe I just missed it. I don't have enough rep on superuser to have access to an `edit` option, so I can't see the source for the answer.

How do I make those cool key stroke combinations in markdown?

Comment: Try hitting down, down-forward, forward and then hitting Enter.

Comment: Speaking seriously, it's `<kbd>Key</kbd>`, as detailed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48939/how-do-i-insert-the-images-of-keys-in-stackoverflow-superuser). See also [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36785/could-the-kbd-tag-be-added-to-the-stackoverflow-editing-help) suggesting to add this into the markdown reference.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

```
<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>
```

outputs:

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

Comment: <kbd>kbd</kbd> should work in comments as well.

Comment: @rid It seems not to?

Comment: <kbd>check</kbd>

Comment: Nope, <kbd> in comments doesn't do anything.

Comment: This should really be in the editing help.

Comment: Works in Github markdown as well.

Answer (score 7):

As a note, you don't need edit privileges to view the source of an answer or question.

Simply go to the revisions of an answer/question which in this case is:

https://superuser.com/posts/211610/revisions

(`[SITE]/POSTS/[ID]/REVISIONS`)

then click `view source` and it will display the actual source of the answer/question:

`<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> will work if you have escaped your VirtualBox and places the screen shot on your Mac's desktop. You could also use or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> which gives you a cross-hair to select the area you want to capture.`

Comment: Only works when you have the access right to edit a answer.