# Can we have the nicer Apple SE/Ask Different <kbd> tag network-wide?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, kbd

AskDifferent has recently got [a nicer `<kbd>` tag](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7556/how-do-i-use-the-right-to-left-override-in-safari-for-mac/7559#7559):

[image]

Could we get it on other SE sites too? I really like that new style.

Comment: Could you link to an actual sample? It'll save people the trouble of digging through the site and hoping they come across one.

Comment: Yep, I've added one.

Comment: a BETTER example (in my ever so humble opinion) http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/183/mac-os-x-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Oh, that looks much better with @Simon's image. On my IE8 (hahahahaha, oh self-deprecation, and naturally not going to be a problem for Apple users), it looks... actually quite horrendous, so I was for the longest time wondering why one would ever want it...

Comment: I will make my vote depend on whether this breaks [Pesto's castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive). (Edit: It kind of works! and looks .... interesting.)

Comment: (Not sure if I should upvote as I detest the current rendering, or not as I don't like the usage of `<kbd>` at all, no matter what rendering is used...)

Comment: @Pekka, link? Or did you just use a Markdown preview?

Comment: @Popular the latter. This issue needs careful evaluation from a castle-building point of view. Before that, it cannot move forward.

Comment: For those who are too lazy to create one themselves: screenshot of [the chiclet castle](http://i.imgur.com/zDKni.png)!

Comment: @Popular - The princess is certainly NOT in THAT castle.

Comment: @Polly she could be in the left (uncollapsed) half.

Comment: And @Polly it could be restored with relative ease.

Comment: Next week, on _Extreme Makeover: Castle Edition_...

Comment: Here's an [extreme example](http://imgur.com/287R6,lUrAk#0) of the difference (use Prev/next on the gallery)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. The update to AskDifferent makes `<kbd>`-enclosed things look like Apple keys, which is fine for an Apple site, but shouldn't replace the default network-wide.

The new one *is* pretty, I'll give you that... but the goal isn't to make something that looks exactly like a real key on a real keyboard. The goal is to effectively communicate that the text is supposed to represent a keyboard key. Function should trump aesthetics here.

Comment: Upvoted. Sometimes function should prevail over form. It's ugly, but defines better what a key is

Comment: Can anyone give any example of a keyboard that looks like the current rendering? Even Microsoft's on-screen keyboard shows rounded keys: [vista](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsvista/osk.aspx), [7](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/products/windows7/default.aspx)?

Comment: @Arjan My old keyboards definitely do. My current DELL keyboard is close with the same shape of keys, but it's black with white text. It strikes me as quicker to understand, much like the fact that "Save" icons are still floppy disks.

Comment: Just to be sure, @Grace: we're talking about [this rendering](http://i.imgur.com/YoABB.png), right? (Chrome on a Mac; not much different, if at all, on my other browsers.)

Comment: @Arjan Yes, quite. The R-9DH has a shinier interface not unlike the Mac, but this keyboard here definitely looks like a white-on-black version of that.

Comment: I didn't say it looked like a key; I said that it was clear what it's supposed to represent. I mean, have you ever actually seen [this](http://laurenhs.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/binocular-view.jpg) through binoculars?

Comment: @PopularDemand you took the words out of my mouth.

Comment: To me, the current rendering denoting a keyboard is really only clear because of the text inside it. And I hardly ever need that formatting to understand the context. But, it does make my eyes sad. ;-)

Comment: Hmm, did anyone try to fix Pesto's castle?

Comment: The current rendering looks almost identical to the keys on my IBM Model M. I don't know what you people are talking about.

Answer (score 4):

No, because chiclet keyboards <strike>suck</strike> are inferior to full travel keyboards in terms of tactile feedback.

Comment: @whoever downvoted - Ok wiseguy, show me a chiclet keyboard that is arguably better than a good regular keyboard.  ;-)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the tactile feedback that's most important to me is the little bumps on F and J. I'm used to the "chiclet" keyboard and find the amount of travel in the keys sufficient to determine if I have pressed them or not. My keyboard has several qualities I find desirable: it's durable, thin, and quiet. Those are objective qualities that make it arguably better. Keyboard preference is subjective.