# Add border-radius to make <kbd> look much better

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, kbd

I suggest adding the following CSS to `<kbd>` tags (such as <kbd>Space</kbd>) so that the top right and bottom left corners do not look slightly odd.

Solution is to round those two corners in such a way that they do not exactly look rounded.

`kbd { border-radius: 0 3px; -moz-border-radius: 0 3px; }`

This produces: (Old on the left, new on the right)

[image: Space (old) versus Space (new)]

This slight change will make practical uses much better looking. While still preserving the layout of [all the art that has been created](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1974/152038).

Comment: I can see the difference when I compare the new and old styles side by side, but I don't think I would notice in any other case.

Comment: I just thought it looked a lot more 3-dimensional, where the other one looks like a bit sloppy. This I noticed right away the first time I saw the formatting used. I only just now thought of this tweak. I don't know what the policy is on small tweaks like this, but I thought I would mention it since it seems to be a one-liner. P.S. you could of course use `4px` :)

Comment: Still [too ugly](http://i.stack.imgur.com/P2W2F.png) for me. Ban `<kbd>`!

Comment: +1 to this or something similar. Ask Different already adds a border-radius and a drop-shadow ([example](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/183/)) and it looks good.

Comment: If you want a 3D effect, perhaps you'd be interested in the `outset` property instead? See also [Can we have the nicer Apple SE/Ask Different <kbd> tag network-wide?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78377/131713)

Comment: +1 for this. Definitely an improvement over the current style, but not a breaking design change.

Comment: `<kbd>`, representing user input, should not render to look like keys at all. Like, according to [the w3.org wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/kbd): `input "<kbd>Yes</kbd>" or "<kbd>No</kbd>"`. To represent actual keys, all `<kbd>`'s should be wrapped into a parent `<kbd>`... That looks even worse.

Comment: @Arjan, I think the amount of people who care about having proper display of nested `<kbd>` tags is very small. But it is interesting to know what the original intent was.

Comment: I know, @George, still I was brave enough to boldly ask for downvotes, errr, [Ban <kbd>, its usage and rendering are incorrect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115128/ban-kbd-its-usage-and-rendering-are-incorrect) ;-)

Comment: @Arjan, Are you insane? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyboard styles were adjusted on the trilogy and (hopefully) most SE 2.0 sites where we weren't already doing this.