# Can we use 'kbd' according to its definition in HTML5?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, kbd

**Can the `kbd` element be used according to its [definition in the HTML5 (CR) spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-kbd-element), or do we have further restrictions for its use on *Stack Exchange* sites?**

The [editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) only gives an example, but no definition/help. The linked [answer to "What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/193139) says:

> `<kbd>`            - shows keyboard input

But I’m not sure if this is meant to be *the* definitive definition for its use.

The HTML5 (CR) spec says that `kbd` represents "**user** input", not necessarily "**keyboard** input".

So the following examples should be valid according to HTML5 (CR):

> Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>.

I assume this usage is, without question, appropriate on SE.

> Just press <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd></kbd>.

If someone uses this structure, it often gets edited by someone else, making it look like the first example.

(Also mentioned in [Ban <kbd>, its usage and rendering are incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115128/193139)).)

> Then click on <kbd>Post Your Question</kbd>.

What about this? When I use/saw this, sometimes it gets edited (e.g., removed `kbd` and added `i` or quotation marks), sometimes not.

To make it clear: in this example, `kbd` is not used to make the text *look* like a button, but because it *is* a button, i.e., this text is used on a button which the user should "activate" (whether by keyboard or mouse or voice …).

Just for the record, some more (complex) examples of the previous case:

> - You can find it at <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Export</kbd> → <kbd>Export as XML</kbd>
> - You can find it at <kbd><kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Export</kbd> → <kbd>Export as XML</kbd></kbd>
> - You can find it at <kbd>File → Export → Export as XML</kbd>
> - You can find it at <kbd>File | Export | Export as XML</kbd>

And also (but here could `code` be used instead):

> - Enter <kbd>answers:0</kbd> to find all questions with no answers.

---

While the question [Stricter <kbd> usage rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181774/193139) is about a similar topic, it is mostly about usage that is *wrong* according to HTML5.

Comment: I don't care what HTML 5 says. Are you seeing a problem on the site with people using kbd too much or not enough?

Comment: What is your question or thing you want us to discuss?

Comment: @hichris123: "May we use it according to the spec or not?" which results in "Are the edits (that change the markup as mentioned in my question) correct or not?"

Comment: @KateGregory: When I have used it in cases where it’s not about pressing some keys (like documented in my question), it sometimes gets removed (with edit messages like "kbd is for keyboard keys"), sometimes not.

Comment: Is the second one to indicate that the ctrl and f are pressed together?

Comment: @RichardTingle: The first and second one are equivalent. It’s defined as: "When the `kbd` element is nested inside another `kbd` element, it represents an actual key or other single unit of input as appropriate for the input mechanism." If they were to be pressed together (at the same time), one would probably use it (example 1 or 2) without the `+` character.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't mention that people are using `kbd` tags to link to outside sites like [sql fiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20890469/426671).

Comment: O, in that case I think it is probably to much clutter

Comment: @bluefeet: Yeah, this is definitely not appropriate according to HTML5, and it already gets discussed at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181774/193139

Answer (score 11):

In my opinion, good uses of the `<kbd>` markup include:

- to mark up a single key such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- to mark up a button in the ui being discussed **unless** we are discussing actually writing that ui. So "click <kbd>Post Your Answer</kbd>" is fine in a meta post, but "my <kbd>Submit</kbd> button is not working" is not fine in an SO post
- to mark up a link (rather than a button) subject to the qualifications above, so "click <kbd>flag</kbd> to flag a post for moderator attention"

Bad uses include:

- general emphasis: "be <kbd>very</kbd> careful" is as bad as "be `very` careful"
- making a link you're providing somehow look cool: <kbd>jsfiddle here</kbd> is bad, bad, bad!
- code labels or elements in a code-focused post, even if those elements are actually buttons
- making giant castles (I [found the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive), it was awesome. But wrong. But awesome.)

Also see [Stricter <kbd> usage rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181774/147247)

If someone edits away a usage that is meant to represent a user interface element (even if it's not strictly a keyboard key) that's just their opinion. You can roll the change back.

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue noted in the question.

Comment: @FEichinger The question specifically asks "can I use it for Post Your Question?" and mentions others editing it away if it's not for a keystroke. This answers that.

Answer (score 5):

I am fine with this one:

> Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>.

This one is too much clutter:

> Just press <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd></kbd>.

Who knows, maybe it will soon grow to 3- and more levels, if encouraged.

However, I think `kbd` should be a *documented* function and show on toolbar in WYSIWYG editor.

**EDIT:** In my opinion, `kbd` should only be used for keyboard/mouse shortcuts, to stay with semantics (let's refer to them collectively as *user input devices*, someone may otherwise not like joysticks not being mentioned etc.). Menu items can be displayed using `code` outline or just go AS IS.

To avoid confusion, we can change the style of `kbd` to something that looks more like a key, rather than a button control:

[image]

If really necessary, we could have another tag called `<menu>`, displaying like this:

[image] (Visual Studio 2010).

Or just keep the current `kbd` style.

Comment: At some point in history, someone made a sandbox post to see how many levels of nested kbd could be used. There must have been at least two dozen. I seem to remember it breaking some browsers. Repeating this experiment is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @Pops: SO could have a checker to eliminate nested `<kbd>`s - should solve the problem, if anyone dares to do it again.

Comment: Eh. I don't remember anyone ever abusing it in practice other than that one time.

Comment: Ànd what about using it for *keyboard* input vs. *user* input? In other words: are you fine with using `kbd` for every kind of input, as long as several `kbd` elements don’t get nested? Or are you fine with using it for keyboard keys only, as long as several `kbd` elements don’t get nested?

Comment: @unor: See my edit. My preference is using `kbd` as keyboard/mouse shortcuts only.

Comment: @Neolisk: You wrote "to stay with semantics". What do you mean by that? HTML specs defines how an element should be used (and therefore, its "semantics"), and according to HTML5, `kbd` can be used for, e.g., menu items. So it’s especially *not* about input *devices*, but *input*. Using `code` for menu items is, in general, not appropriate.

Comment: @unor: Semantics of the word `<kbd>`, which most likely would be read as `keyboard` by 99.9% of the users. Originally, keyboard was the only input device, there were no mice in the old days. Hence, the image. Same as 3.5in diskette showing as a `Save` icon. Younger generation has no idea why `Save` option is a 3.5in diskette icon BTW. Regarding the abuse of `code`, I've seen much worse examples than highlighting the menu options.

Comment: kbd used to look like an old clacky keyboard key on Stack Overflow. Jin later made it into the chiclet thingy.

Comment: @Manishearth: Was there any particular reason for this change? Some discussion on meta, maybe?

Comment: Don't know, ask Jin. It looks better than the older one, though.

Comment: @Manishearth: Well, it adds confusion - I am all with OP for that matter. Yes, designers can get carried away, but typically any change in production environment has a strong reason, such as that it increases productivity, maintainability etc. If it just `looks cool`, it's subjective, and usually to be discussed. Remember, old DOS apps did not look cool at all, but some were very productive and are still used these days (major retail stores etc.).

Comment: @Neolisk Not that it looked cool, but the older one was ugly. Also, there were some issues where the older one was too fat to fit in its own line and caused overlap.

Comment: @Manishearth: Again, changing something because it's ugly is usually not a valid reason for a change. If it did cause an overlap, I am sure designers and HTML developers could figure something out. All it needs to be a trapeze-like 3D image, it does not have to be deep, shadowed, with glare etc. The problem is that by making it look like a button, they changed the meaning. Unless they intended to, of course.

Comment: @Neolisk Most laptop keys look like that these days.

Comment: @Manishearth: As I mentioned before, there is no particular reason why `Save` button looks like a diskette today, yet it still looks like that, in many applications. Keeping the traditions is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: @Neolisk Neither is shifting to new symbols. The save button is ubiquitous, the trapezoid key, not so much. Besides, I've seen folks abusing kbd markup before the design change, so I don't think that would fix it.

Comment: @Manishearth: The new symbol is confusing. By making it look flat, its meaning was expanded. If you do a [hallway usability testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usability_testing) with people who never dealt with SO, they will tell you the same. I believe SO should be easy to start using, so new people don't get confused. Myself - I am totally okay with any meaning you put into it, as I am rarely using it anyway.

Comment: @Neolisk That is all completely irrelevant to the discussion at hand, though. None of this has anything to do with the *styling* of the tag. (In fact, the styling currently does not fully comply with the semantics as per the spec, but that's beside the point, really.)

Comment: *"This one is too much clutter"* -- are you referring to the rendering? (Then I agree, but then the rendering is wrong, I feel.)

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, the appearance. My opinion is that `You can find it at` #1 looks best. Really, cannot see a need for nested `<kbd>`s. If you can suggest a use case, please feel free to post as an answer.

Comment: The use case for the nested element is what this very question is all about... Preferring one over the other *just because the formatting on SE is wrong* seems a bit odd to me.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, it doesn't really matter. The thing you have to consider here is the appearance of your post. Yes, that element is great for semantically marking up user input, but it also *destroys* the readability of a post when used excessively or used in an environment where the styles make it an eye-sore.

Generally, when browsing through posts, you want to see keyboard key looking things *as little as possible*. I tend to stick to the rule of only using them for actual keyboard keys because that's about all of the keyboard styling I can handle. If you're using the markup for, say, 50 different keyboard combinations in a single post, I would say using the markup is a bad thing - that would look atrocious.

Obviously here on Stack Exchange, nested input elements are out of the question because the styles here just plain don't support that usage. It's ugly and would probably just confuse users reading your post. Past that, I prefer just using bold, but it's really up to you.

In summary: meh.

Comment: If the styles make semantic markup unreadable, then it's the styles that are at fault and not the markup.

Comment: @george The styles are at fault, and we've been trying ro get them changed. But making a post look odd and comfusing for visitors coming for an answer is still a pretty serious issue that should be avoided. If removing nesting is all we have to work with, then that's what should be done.

Comment: "The thing you have to consider here is the appearance of your post" -- in which user agent, and with what settings? The separation of content and style is one of the great things about Web technology: let's not trade that for a world where the semantics implied by some Web site's specific CSS are more important than the semantics defined by the specifications, especially on a site where we're teaching people about development.

Comment: @george Those are the same arguments we've all made for changing it, but in this case removing the nesting doesn't change the semantic meaning much at all, and I think the benefit of having the post look normal outweighs a user's desire to semantically group some user input elements together. Personally, I would never know because I have custom CSS that removes all the styling from a kbd around another kbd, so the post won't look different to me either way.

Comment: Chiming in to say that using `kbd:has(kbd)` could be used to reset the general style when they are nested so only the inner-most kbds are styled. Unfortunately this hasn't gained browser support, which highlights the issue: there is no trivial way in CSS to style this the "right way" for `<kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd></kbd>`.