# Denoting buttons in Stack Exchange posts

Tags: support, markdown

Is there a way, similar to denoting keyboard shortcuts, to denote buttons on SE posts?  I thought it would make things much more readable.

Comment: Do you have an example of a post where you feel this *denoting* of buttons would help in readability?

Comment: What do you mean by "denoting buttons"? I've never heard that term/phrase.

Comment: Well, for example, if I wrote: "Click the **`Add Comment`** button at the right of the comment text-field," I'd want to show some kind of button image rather than using a codeblock, for example, or a kbd block, or a bold block, because it's more readable.

Comment: I also had to google @ShadowWizard http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/denote

Comment: What's wrong with a kbd block?

Comment: No, there's no such way.

Comment: @rene Oh, I get it now :) If you've never heard of the word "denote" before it looks like de-note, as in "taking the notes out" or "removing/stripping the notes"! That's quite funny. Lol.

Comment: I think tag is nice, but I hope it doesn't screw up search engines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there isn't.

If you don't want to abuse <kbd>button</kbd> or [button](/questions/tagged/button) or **button** or *button* or <sup>button</sup> or <sub>button</sub> you're out of luck.

The very creative could probably abuse some unicode but I guess that is about it.

```
<kbd>button</kbd>
[tag:button]
**button**
*button*
<sup>button</sup>
<sub>button</sub>
```

Or pick some other options from the [allowed html](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/158100) to see if you can construct something that resembles a button better then my futile attempt.

With the kind help of [Andras Deak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5067311/andras-deak) this beauty came up: 📻  [Radio button](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/128251) or experiment with [this](http://lunicode.com/flip)

Comment: Using `kbd` markup in something like "Click the *Add Comment* button" [is not *abusing* it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215133/193139).

Comment: `[tag:button]` doesn't work if there are spaces like [tag:Add Comment] :/

Comment: @David of course not, tags can't have spaces and never meant to be abused for markdown to begin with. Personally I'll roll back and remove such horrible formatting.