# Should 'click' be used with <kbd>?

Tags: discussion, best-practices, kbd

When denoting a key combination, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+click, should *click* be shown as a button as well for better readability? (as such: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd>)

Comment: I would say that things that are not a key or keystroke shouldn't be marked with `<kbd>`. If the thin appearance of click is bothersome in the overall appearance of the post consider a bold **click**

Comment: Perhaps there should be a `<mouse>left</mouse>` and `<mouse>right</mouse>` (or similar) that inserts something like  or ️ but with the left/right button being the only shaded part. When I have to write SOPs I often add [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlTad.png) (taken from Windows' system tray when using mousekeys) to screenshots in order to show where to left-click. [Edit: something like [this](http://www.iconarchive.com/show/windows-8-icons-by-icons8/Computer-Hardware-Mouse-Left-Click-icon.html) would work too.]

Comment: 3D1T0R - That seems like a great solution that shouldn't be difficult to implement, whereas manually adding a picture every time for readability can be a pain. I'll use your method until we get that on here!

Comment: 117 questions in the [meta-tag:best-practices] tag. Ew. Also, no close reason for opinion based. Ew.

Comment: Won't - Sorry... What?

Comment: related or perhaps even a dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215133/can-we-use-kbd-according-to-its-definition-in-html5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `<kbd>` indicator can be used for tons of things!

- not only keyboards:

<kbd>Esc</kbd>      <kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>    <kbd>F5</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>    <kbd>F9</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>    <kbd>[Prnt](http://meta.stackexchange.com)</kbd>  <kbd>[Scrl](http://meta.stackexchange.com)</kbd>  <kbd>[Pse](http://meta.stackexchange.com)</kbd> 

  <kbd>`</kbd>   <kbd>1</kbd>   <kbd>2</kbd>   <kbd>3</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd>   <kbd>5</kbd>   <kbd>6</kbd>   <kbd>7</kbd>   <kbd>8</kbd>   <kbd>9</kbd>   <kbd>0</kbd>   <kbd>-</kbd>   <kbd>=</kbd>     <kbd>Bks</kbd>        <kbd>Ins</kbd>  <kbd>Hme</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd>

 <kbd>Tab</kbd>   <kbd>Q</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd>   <kbd>E</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>   <kbd>T</kbd>   <kbd>Y</kbd>   <kbd>U</kbd>   <kbd>I</kbd>   <kbd>O</kbd>   <kbd>P</kbd>   <kbd>[</kbd>  <kbd>]</kbd> <kbd>Entr</kbd>    <kbd>Del</kbd>  <kbd>End</kbd> <kbd>PgDn</kbd>

 <kbd>[Caps](http://meta.stackexchange.com)</kbd>   <kbd>A</kbd>   <kbd>S</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd>   <kbd>F</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>   <kbd>H</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>   <kbd>K</kbd>   <kbd>L</kbd>   <kbd>;</kbd>   <kbd>'</kbd>  <kbd>#</kbd>       

 <kbd>[Shift](http://meta.stackexchange.com)</kbd>  <kbd>\</kbd>   <kbd>Z</kbd>   <kbd>X</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>   <kbd>B</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>   <kbd>M</kbd>   <kbd>,</kbd>   <kbd>.</kbd>   <kbd>/</kbd>        <kbd>[Shift](http://meta.stackexchange.com)</kbd>                    <kbd>↑</kbd>  

 <kbd>[Ctrl](http://meta.stackexchange.com)</kbd>  <kbd>[❖](http://meta.stackexchange.com)</kbd>   <kbd>[Alt](http://meta.stackexchange.com)</kbd>                                                                  <kbd>[Alt](http://meta.stackexchange.com)</kbd>   <kbd>[❖](http://meta.stackexchange.com)</kbd>   <kbd>[≡](http://meta.stackexchange.com)</kbd>  
 <kbd>[Ctrl](http://meta.stackexchange.com)</kbd>      <kbd>←</kbd>    <kbd>↓</kbd>     <kbd>→</kbd>

- and individual keys like <kbd>F1</kbd>
- but also for buttons like <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>Retry</kbd>, <kbd>Cancel</kbd>
- Key combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>
- menu items like <kbd>System Settings</kbd> (Yup, in Ubuntu that's a menu item!)
- so why not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Click</kbd>?

*Just ensure you're using a consistent UI methodology within the same Question or Answer!*

Comment: I suppose that, as with other subjective style-related things, consistency is more important than the actual style choice you make.

Comment: On Arqade (Gaming SE), it's not uncommon for `kbd` to be used for controller buttons as well. [Example](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/260986/28182)

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: I would avoid this unless you have a specific and strong reason for doing it.

The system suggested by Fabby in [the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311579/) is commonly used in practice—even, admittedly, sometimes by me—but not strictly correct. It's based on the assumption that things wrapped in `<kbd>` markup will *look* like buttons, together with an unwritten underlying rule that form trumps function.

To be technical, the `<kbd>` element

> represents a span of inline text denoting **textual user input** from a keyboard, voice input, or any other text entry device

*(emphasis mine)*

[according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/kbd). If you prefer WHATWG, [its page about the element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-kbd-element) is similar, if drier.

Now, I didn't learn this until I was in the middle of writing this answer, but in [the HTML 5.2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/textlevel-semantics.html#the-kbd-element), W3C actually does expand its definition of `<kbd>` to

> The `<kbd>` element represents user input (typically keyboard input, although it may also be used to represent other input, such as voice commands).

So, in fairness, representing a click this way *may* not be considered semantically wrong, depending on your spec, although it's still no good for menu items or pure decoration.

My main gripe here was originally about accessibility. People relying on markup to actually describe content are put at a disadvantage when semantically incorrect items are used. The W3C HTML5.2 spec diminishes that argument some, but it's still relying on users (and their assistive technologies) to be following the "right" spec.

Additionally, not all browsers/technologies may render a given element the same way. If someone is using a custom stylesheet (again, possibly an accessibility issue) or a text-based reader (uncommon, but [not nonexistent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=lynx)), the intended message of a decorative `<kbd>` use may not be communicated.