# <kbd /> elements are still intrusive

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, kbd

I have just edited [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/404716/xmodmap-configuration) where OP is apparently not afraid to talk about his <kbd>k</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.

Now look at that mess. <kbd>F1</kbd>s fighting each other...

[image: all the KBDs...]

I'm not a CSS person, but think that making he `<kbd/>`ized font little bit smaller could prevent keys from overlapping.

I believe that `<kbd/>` should be usable as *markup*, without such devastating effect on visual part.

(I know `<kbd/>`s [used to be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive) more intrusive back in old days of Pesto's castles.)

Comment: YOU CAN HAVE MY `kbd` TAG WHEN YOU PRY THEM FROM MY COLD, DEAD HANDS!

Comment: Perhaps you'd be interested in supporting [this other feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78377/can-we-have-the-nicer-apple-se-ask-different-kbd-tag-network-wide)?

Comment: @TheEstablishment I'd love to see those *Appl*ovely tags applied on my example :)

Comment: I agree it's too intrusive (and also [some would say](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-kbd-element) it's even wrong and one should use an additional pair: `<kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd><key>F1</kbd> </kbd>`). But what is keeping you from rolling back that edit?

Comment: @Arjan I did the markup intentionally because I think that markup should be done. (...no matter the real influence on display and/or formatting.) I don't want to revert it, I just don't like how it looks like.

Comment: @Arjan (That "feel wrong" part was meant ironically, I have removed it since now I realize it can be misleading.)

Comment: (Hmmm, I'd *almost* remove my upvote as I really feel your edit was too excessive and I dislike `<kbd>` for both its ugly rendering and wrong usage. But well, as I'm afraid it's here to stay, making it less intrusive helps a bit too...)

Answer (score 14):

Our designer, [Jin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin), has much improved the styles on `<kbd>` elements.

View an example here: [<kbd> elements are way intrusive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1950#1950)

(Forgive the broken castle above it)

Comment: Why should I forgive the castle? It has done nothing wrong. On the other hand, **I HATE JIN FOREVER.**

Comment: Could we have the less-bad <kbd>s network-wide, or at least on [gaming.se] as well? Looks like this was only deployed to the trilogy sites.

Comment: Yep. http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/mathjax-buttons-hotkeys-script

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: [The castle has been reincarnated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131634/178438) :)

Comment: I agree with @lunboks, can we have the pretty keys on all sites (like, for example, [tex.se]) pretty please?

Comment: @Jarrod - Arqade is [still waiting](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4633/could-we-have-the-new-kbd-tag) for a response, either yay or nay. Any chance you could prod Jin a bit? :)

Comment: @Robotnik consider him prodded.

Answer (score 7):

Just for visual comparison, what I was able to manage with couple of `!important` attributes on Opera on my Debian box (the same machine as I used for the first example):

[image: Example of the same post with x-small font-size and some position adjustments]

I.e.:

```
kbd {
    font-size:x-small !important;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 3px !important;
    padding:1px 4px !important;
}
```

(Please don't blast me for incorrect CSS practices ;-D)

Answer (score 1):

#### Well...yeah . . .

I mean, bold would be intrusive too, if you used that much of it. A little bit of formatting goes a long way.

I don't really think this is a problem that is inherent to the styling used for the `<kbd>` tag...

Comment: Yes, the same way using too much emphasis in real speech would be. But unlike **bold**, the `<kbd/>` is not meant to emphasize. And I don't see such way as mentioning keyboard shortcuts too much.

Comment: @Alois: it *is* emphasis though. It emphasizes that it's a keystroke. The way you might *say* "Hold the Control **key**, the Alt **key**, and then press the Delete **key** in order to save your game" when doing phone support, but merely say "press control-alt-delete" when speaking to a co-worker who already knows that these are keys.

Comment: @Shog9 your point of view proves that there are other points of view than mine. Thanks. But (from Wikipedia): "emphasis is the exaggeration of words in a text with a font in a different style from the rest of the text—to emphasize them." When I review for markup, I do not want to think about what the rendering engine will make it look like (will it actually emphasize or not?). I merely want to preserve the information that this _is_ a keystroke. Just as when you insert an `<a/>`nchor among other data: You don't really want to say "make it blue and underline it", do you?

Comment: I sympathize with your point of view, @Alois - and I do like your mock-up: the overlap shown in your question's screenshot is wrong no matter how you slice it. But I do think these are supposed to stand out a bit - you *want* them to be noticed.

Comment: Thanks, @Shog9. Yes, even I actually *do* want them to stand out a little---In a diffenent way on SO site, on Apple site, on mobile SE, on archaic-wooden-keyboards-club-site or when viewing any of those in Lynx.