# Was the Ask Different <kbd> style implemented?

Tags: support, specific-question, kbd

While browsing SE, I came across a request to implement Ask Different's `<kbd>` tag style network-wide. (*[Can we have the nicer Apple SE/Ask Different <kbd> tag network-wide?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78377/351462)*.)

[image: Apple Style KBD tags]

[The accepted answer by Pops](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78378/351462) explains that the feature will not be implemented.

> **No. The update to AskDifferent makes `<kbd>`-enclosed things look like Apple keys, which is fine for an Apple site, but shouldn't replace the default network-wide.**
>
> The new one is pretty, I'll give you that... but the goal isn't to make something that looks exactly like a real key on a real keyboard. The goal is to effectively communicate that the text is supposed to represent a keyboard key. Function should trump aesthetics here.

Despite the negative moderator response, [the post was tagged as](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/78377/5) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) by Jeff Atwood a few years back.

Assuming that the change *was* implemented:

- What did `<kbd>` look like before the change?
- What were the reasons SE changed its mind?
- Why does <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> look different than [image]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Exchange didn't change its mind. It never gave an opinion on it before completing the request.

Pops was not an employee when he posted that answer. He wasn't hired [until 2013](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/09/06/community-management-by-popular-demand-kevin-chang-joins-the-team/). Those were just his personal opinions on the subject, that the asker happened to agree with and accepted.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126998/kbd-elements-are-still-intrusive) has a nice comparison of the old vs new styles.