# Allow <kbd> in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, kbd

Simple feature request really. Currently, using `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>` in a comment, prints the code without markdown. If `code highlighting` tags are allowed, I don't see why `<kbd>` shouldn't be. It'd be nice to show the correct <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

**Edit:** Feel free to close this question. I hadn't seen the dupe until I posted the question (I did search).

Comment: <kbd>test</kbd>

Comment: Is there a comment in particular where this would have made things much easier to read? If I type ctrl-alt-del, or `ctrl-alt-del` it reads fine to me. My main concern here is people having [too much fun with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71407/50049), comments are quite noisy to begin with - even though castles are cool.

Comment: @TimPost The comment I wrote that made me think of this wouldn't have been made much easier to read with `<kbd>`, since it was only 1 key I wanted to format. It seems I've stumbled upon a "don't mention the war" topic, hadn't seen that thread before! But you're right, castles are cool :p

Comment: @TimPost: [You don't need no `<kbd>`s to play around!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/131926#131926)