# Inappropriate use of `kbd` tag

Tags: discussion, kbd

I've noticed a handful of users (mis)using the `kbd` tag to style links into something that looks like a button. For example:

<kbd>[**StackOverflow**](http://stackoverflow.com)</kbd>

This smells a lot like HTML ≤ 4 to me. I don't think there's any need to [change the style of kbd elements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive) (again), especially since the current styles are useful to show keystroke sequences, but maybe it's worth considering supporting a way to style a link like a button without much work.

Any consensus on whether this usage should discouraged?

I've already edited a handful of answers to remove the arguably abused `kbd` tags where they are unhelpful, fwiw.

Comment: How about `<bttn>`?

Comment: What's wrong with a plain link?

Comment: @hammar Nothing, but apparently my opinion isn't shared by all.

Comment: I brought this up a day or two ago as a feature request suggesting a standardized "button link", it didn't go over well... It received at least 8 down-votes in the first hour or so, I gave up and deleted it.

Comment: Wait! I thought `<kbd>` was disabled for meta?

Comment: @Cole I understand you never visited the formatting sandbox?

Comment: @Cole Johnson: Since when was a button input the XHTML equivalent of a button?

Comment: @Cole nope, only the quality filter is disabled markdown is the same like in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Cole Johnson: Neither in that. A button is a button, and a button input is a button input. This is true in both HTML and XHTML (and all relevant versions).