# Can we have arrow key navigation in site stack exchange dropdown?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, top-bar

A common practice in "search bar with filtering result" is usage of   <kbd>▲</kbd>    <kbd>▼</kbd>   arrows keys.  Can we have this feature in ***More Stack Exchange Communities*** in Stack Exchange dropdown in top bar?

[image]

<sup>picked those arrows keys from [@RichardTheKiwi 's thoughts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156177/233367)</sup>