# Should "How to use <kbd> tags" be included in the "How To Format" list?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing-help

I have noticed that many edits by members of various SE sites are to change keystrokes like CTRL + A to the proper <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> format.

Should information on how to properly use key command formatting be included 
in the "How To Format" list (i.e. when trying to post your question)? I think we could promote site consistency, and help save a lot of energy of the editing task force by implementing this.

Comment: +1 ....maybe only on technology sites -- the others don't really need it as much. ( *similar to how MathJax instructions are only found on the science and math sites* )

Comment: And maybe hint about the Windows or Apple symbol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I definitely think this is a good idea.

Although [we've all seen `<kbd>`'s go bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive), so it might be nice to have a little "you can use the `<kbd>` tag, but make sure you use it for good" disclaimer. Basically just a sentence that indicates <kbd>Don't <kbd>do<kbd>anything<kbd>like<kbd><kbd><kbd>this</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>.

I think it's good practice to show new users all (or at least most) of the options available to them. I haven't seen anything of the sort be an actual problem for a long time, although that could just mean I'm hanging out in the wrong (right?) tags. But let's not let that come back into style by teaching people how to do something with no indication of when to (or not to) do it. Of course that's more relevant to the [Advanced Formatting Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page, where there'd actually be space to take an entire sentence, and that page already has a [slight reference to them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#html) in a single example.

But yes, on the whole, I think it does a lot for readability and engagement when there are actually keyboard keys involved, so it's definitely worth teaching new users about it.

Comment: Don't tell people they can do that, and they won't know LOL 

Keep it secret, keep it safe

Answer (score 2):

Well, technically speaking, from the editing help page:

> If you need to do something that Markdown can't handle, use HTML. [Note
>   that we only support a very strict subset of HTML!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed)

And that link does list `kbd` as an allowed HTML tag. If we document `kbd`, should `dl` and `dd` be documented as well?

Perhaps it could be made more obvious, but I don't think it's that important honestly. After all, if a user comes across a post with <kbd>something like this</kbd> he can always [edit] to view the source, and see how it's written.