# Chat bug: tags has got too small line-height

Tags: bug, design, chat

That's a terrible bug!
An upper tag is eating lower tag!

Obviously, I mean that a tag in the next line eats the border of the tag on the previous line.

Not that it's a problem, though, but I *had* to report it.

[image]

Comment: I kinda like it.

Comment: But what does it look like if the tags are different lengths?

Comment: Apparently, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Dsg.png

Comment: We all know [where that's going to lead.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1974)