# Weird boxes in question title and body

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question

I've just noticed these weird boxes in this specific question. Is this normal or does this look like a bug?

It even appears in this link-generated sentence:

[Javascript line-height Property with ██████](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58981055/1244884)

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: It's clear from the QR code just below it that it's intended. It's, █, the character they're using to display the QR code.

Comment: Ah sorry - it didn't occur to me that these could be characters. Cheers.

Comment: [████████](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2588/index.htm)

Comment: Will they be more or less awesome for [building castles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-too-intrusive/1974#1974)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIL - These are legitimate characters like emojis...

[image]

Comment: They precede emojis by many, *many* years: https://theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/block-graphic-character-ascii-code-219.html

Comment: Yeah, [WordPerfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPerfect)!